# Hibernate, JDBC and Java performance on medium and big result set

Tags: java, mysql, performance, hibernate, jdbc

#Issue#
We are trying to optimize our dataserver application.
It stores stocks and quotes over a mysql database.
And we are not satisfied with the fetching performances.

#Context#
- database
- table stock : around 500 lines
- table quote : 3 000 000 to 10 000 000 lines
- one-to-many association : one stock owns n quotes
- fetching around 1000 quotes per request
- there is an index on (stockId,date) in the quote table
- no cache, because in production, queries are always different
- Hibernate 3
- mysql 5.5
- Java 6
- JDBC mysql Connector 5.1.13
- c3p0 pooling

#Tests and results#
##Protocol##

- Execution times on mysql server are obtained with running the generated sql queries in mysql command line bin.
- The server is in a test context : no other DB readings, no DB writings
- We fetch 857 quotes for the AAPL stock

##Case 1 : Hibernate with association##
This fills up our stock object with 857 quotes object (everything correctly mapped in hibernate.xml)

```
session.enableFilter("after").setParameter("after", 1322910573000L);
Stock stock = (Stock) session.createCriteria(Stock.class).
add(Restrictions.eq("stockId", stockId)).
setFetchMode("quotes", FetchMode.JOIN).uniqueResult();
```

SQL generated :

```
SELECT this_.stockId AS stockId1_1_,
       this_.symbol AS symbol1_1_,
       this_.name AS name1_1_,
       quotes2_.stockId AS stockId1_3_,
       quotes2_.quoteId AS quoteId3_,
       quotes2_.quoteId AS quoteId0_0_,
       quotes2_.value AS value0_0_,
       quotes2_.stockId AS stockId0_0_,
       quotes2_.volume AS volume0_0_,
       quotes2_.quality AS quality0_0_,
       quotes2_.date AS date0_0_,
       quotes2_.createdDate AS createdD7_0_0_,
       quotes2_.fetcher AS fetcher0_0_
FROM stock this_
LEFT OUTER JOIN quote quotes2_ ON this_.stockId=quotes2_.stockId
AND quotes2_.date > 1322910573000
WHERE this_.stockId='AAPL'
ORDER BY quotes2_.date ASC
```

Results :

- Execution time on mysql server : **~10 ms**
- Execution time in Java : **~400ms**

##Case 2 : Hibernate without association without HQL##
Thinking to increase performance, we've used that code that fetch only the quotes objects and we manually add them to a stock (so we don't fetch repeated info about the stock for every line). We used createSQLQuery to minimize effects of aliases and HQL mess.

```
String filter = " AND q.date>1322910573000";
filter += " ORDER BY q.date DESC";
Stock stock = new Stock(stockId);
stock.addQuotes((ArrayList<Quote>) session.createSQLQuery("select * from quote q where stockId='" + stockId + "' " + filter).addEntity(Quote.class).list());
```

SQL generated :

```
SELECT *
FROM quote q
WHERE stockId='AAPL'
  AND q.date>1322910573000
ORDER BY q.date ASC
```

Results :

- Execution time on mysql server : **~10 ms**
- Execution time in Java : **~370ms**

##Case 3 : JDBC without Hibernate##

```
String filter = " AND q.date>1322910573000";
filter += " ORDER BY q.date DESC";
Stock stock = new Stock(stockId);
Connection conn = SimpleJDBC.getConnection();
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from quote q where stockId='" + stockId + "' " + filter);
while(rs.next())
{
    stock.addQuote(new Quote(rs.getInt("volume"), rs.getLong("date"), rs.getFloat("value"), rs.getByte("fetcher")));
}
stmt.close();
conn.close();
```

Results :

- Execution time on mysql server : **~10 ms**
- Execution time in Java : **~100ms**

#Our understandings#

- The JDBC driver is common to all the cases.
- There is a fundamental time cost in JDBC driving.
- With similar sql queries, Hibernate spends more time than pure JDBC code in converting result sets in objects.
- Hibernate createCriteria, createSQLQuery or createQuery are similar in time cost.
- In production, where we have lots of writing concurrently, pure JDBC solution seemed to be slower than the hibernate one (maybe because our JDBC solutions was not pooled)
- Mysql wise, the server seems to behave very well, and the time cost is very acceptable.

#Our questions#

- Is there a way to optimize the performance of JDBC driver ?
- And will Hibernate benefit this optimization ?
- Is there a way to optimize Hibernate performance when converting result sets ?
- Are we facing something not tunable because of Java fundamental object and memory management ?
- Are we missing a point, are we stupid and all of this is vain ?
- Are we french ? Yes.

Your help is very welcome.

Comment: Have you profiled this using Yourkit profiler or a similar product? Where do you lose the most speed? With TCP/IP? With object creation? Note: I doubt that a properly configured JDBC solution would ever be slower than a Hibernate one...

Comment: I agree, the pure JDBC solution was probably suffering lack of pooling.

Comment: The difference in time for the pure JDBC solution could very well be the time that is needed to send the data over the network. The call `rs.getByte("fetcher")` seems to indicate you are transferring BLOB data. How big is that data?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You meant `rs.getBytes()`? `getByte()` shouldn't cause any issues, I guess?

Comment: @LukasEder: oh! I missed the fact that there was no `s` (blush).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you do a smoke test with the simples query possible like:

```
SELECT current_timestamp()
```

or

```
SELECT 1 + 1
```

This will tell you what is the actual JDBC driver overhead. Also it is not clear whether both tests are performed from the same machine.

> Is there a way to optimize the performance of JDBC driver ?

Run the same query several thousand times in Java. JVM needs some time to warm-up (class-loading, JIT). Also I assume `SimpleJDBC.getConnection()` uses C3P0 connection pooling - the cost of establishing a connection is pretty high so first few execution could be slow.

Also prefer named queries to ad-hoc querying or criteria query.

> And will Hibernate benefit this optimization ?

Hibernate is a very complex framework. As you can see it consumes 75% of the overall execution time compared to raw JDBC. If you need raw ORM (no lazy-loading, dirty checking, advanced caching), consider [mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/). Or maybe even [`JdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) with [`RowMapper`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapper.html) abstraction.

> Is there a way to optimize Hibernate performance when converting result sets ?

Not really. Check out the [*Chapter 19. Improving performance*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html) in Hibernate documentation. There is *a lot* of reflection happening out there + class generation. Once again, Hibernate might not be a best solution when you want to squeeze every millisecond from your database.

**However** it is a good choice when you want to increase the overall user experience due to extensive caching support. Check out the [*performance*](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html) doc again. It mostly talks about caching. There is a first level cache, second level cache, query cache... This is the place where Hibernate might actually outperform simple JDBC - it can cache a lot in a ways you could not even imagine. On the other hand - poor cache configuration would lead to even slower setup.

Check out: [Caching with Hibernate + Spring - some Questions!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405417)

> Are we facing something not tunable because of Java fundamental object and memory management ?

JVM (especially in *server* configuration) is quite fast. Object creation on the heap is as fast as on the stack in e.g. C, garbage collection has been greatly optimized. I don't think the Java version running plain JDBC would be much slower compared to more native connection. That's why I suggested few improvements in your benchmark.

> Are we missing a point, are we stupid and all of this is vain ?

I believe that JDBC is a good choice if performance is your biggest issue. Java has been used successfully in a lot of database-heavy applications.

Comment: What do you think about deactivating Hibernate's 2nd level caching (if that is even possible)? Couldn't that speed things up remarkably?

Comment: @LukasEder: Hibernate's 2nd level cache is disabled by default. I believe (although I encourage you to profile this) that most of the time is spent in reflection code in Hibernate - which you can't really avoid.

Comment: I didn't know it was deactivated by default, thanks for the hint. I agree with the need for profiling.