# Java list of uninstantiated classes

Tags: java, class

Is it possible to construct a `List<Object>` wherein the elements are uninstantiated classes, with the intention of getting one of the list elements and running a static method from that class or instantiating a new instance of that class? Also, how might one do this and how inadvisable is it (and why)?

To add some context: I want to make an application which generates a randomized city, placing buildings in the city, where each building is an instance of one of the many building classes, each inheriting from an abstract base class. To choose a building appropriate for a certain piece of land, the program may iterate over a list of all possible building classes, checking whether the required parameters can be met for that building (minimum / maximum height, footprint, shape, etc.) or these classes may be stored in some other manner, possibly using maps or some other structures. The bottom line is that I need to store (refferences?) to uninstantiated classes.

Comment: I would have a list of "factories that know how to create the appropriate object", if practical - really depends upon where this data comes from and what role it has.

Comment: Preferably a `List<F extends FactoryInterface>`.

Comment: This is a very good suggestion and especially impressive considering you made it before I added context to my post. I may very well go this route. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot store types, but you can store the [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) object for each class loaded by the JVM.  When the JVM loads and initializes a class on the classpath, it creates a single `Class` object for that class.

The `Class` class gives you access to a number of instance methods for performing [reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) on your program.

> Also, how might one do this and how inadvisable is it (and why)?

For example

```
List<Class<?>> classes = new ArrayList<>();
classes.add(Example.class);
```

Now you can go through the elements and call different methods depending on what you want to do. If you want to create a new instance (and your class has a no-arg constructor), you can do

```
classes.get(0).newInstance();
```

If you don't have a no-argument constructor, you will need to get [`Constructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html) references from the `Class` object.

If you need to invoke methods (whether `static` or not), you need to get a [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) reference. Read through the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

> how inadvisable is it (and why)?

There are some things you cannot do without reflection, but it is generally discouraged.

- [What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)
- [Java Reflection Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435553/java-reflection-performance)
- [Why should I use reflection?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/123956/why-should-i-use-reflection)
- [Java Reflection: Why is it so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1392351/java-reflection-why-is-it-so-slow)
- [Why is Java's reflection package considered the dark side of the force?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170778/why-is-javas-reflection-package-considered-the-dark-side-of-the-force)

---

You should try to minimize using Reflection when you can very well use the `Factory` pattern to achieve your goals in this situation.

[User user2864740 suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726652/java-list-of-uninstantiated-classes/20726684?noredirect=1#comment31052503_20726652)

> I would have a list of "factories that know how to create the
>   appropriate object", if practical - really depends upon where this
>   data comes from and what role it has.

Comment: That answers my question quite nicely. user2864740 had a good suggestion (comment on my original question above) which I think may interest anyone with the same question as I do. I think it would be good to add that suggestion to the beginning of your answer since, as you say, reflection is "generally discouraged" (now I recall hearing an almost identical warning from my computer science professor who mentioned reflection very briefly).

Comment: @BigEndian What that user suggested is the alternative (probably better in this case) of binding your classes at compile time. Reflection moves that binding to run time.

Comment: Yes, exactly. And doing things at compile time is arguably much cleaner and more robust, which is why I like the suggestion so much.

Comment: I don't think it would hurt to add it to the answer. It is not strictly on topic but it is potentially quite a useful tip. That is your choice though.

Comment: @bigEndian I would prefer they put a full answer, but I've linked their comment for now.

Answer (score 2):

You can instantiate instances of a `Class<?>` like this -

```
List<Class<?>> al = new ArrayList<>();
al.add(java.util.Date.class);
for (Class<?> cls : al) {
  try {
    Constructor<?> ctor = cls.getConstructor(null);
    Object o = ctor.newInstance(null);
    System.out.println(o);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 
}
```

Which, when I just ran it, output

```
Sun Dec 22 00:56:06 EST 2013
```

Comment: This was very helpful for me, my scenario included the complexity that the Classes over which I was iterating all extended an abstract class which I could cast `Object o` to, and then call the abstract methods.  I'm still dubious of my patterns, but your answer helped close my loop.