# Kotlin list of uninstantiated classes

Tags: android, kotlin

This question is basically a copy of ["Java list of uninstantiated classes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20726652/java-list-of-uninstantiated-classes) but for Kotlin.

My use case is that I have a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and I would like to pass it an `ArrayList` of uninstantiated `Fragment`s. I have an abstract base class `TutorialSlideFragment` that defines a basic class for some slides in a tutorial. Then, I have 20+ `Fragment`s that extend `TutorialSlideFragment` to add some more functionality if needed. I would like to pass an `ArrayList` of uninstantiated `TutorialSlideFragment` so that the adapter can instantiate them in the right class when needed.

Currently, I have the following:

`ArrayList<Class<TutorialSlideFragment>> = arrayListOf(
        TutorialSlideFragment::class.java
 )`

This works, but let's not forget that `TutorialSlideFragment` is abstract, so this is not what I want to do. I created a `WelcomeSlideFragment` that extends `TutorialSlideFragment`. If I do the following:

```
var tutorialSlides: ArrayList<Class<TutorialSlideFragment>> = arrayListOf(
        WelcomeFragment::class.java
)
```

I get the following error:

```
Type inference failed. Expected type mismatch:
required:kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Class<TutorialSlideFragment>>
found:   kotlin.collections.ArrayList<Class<WelcomeFragment>>
```

How can I have an `ArrayList` on uninstantiated classes that extend a base class?

Comment: Try `var tutorialSlides: ArrayList<Class<in TutorialSlideFragment>>`. Or, take a more Kotlin-y approach, and have your list be of lambda expressions that can create the desired fragment, instead of having your adapter rely on reflection.

Comment: @CommonsWare It would need to be covariant, not contravariant in this case.

Comment: @Tenfour04: Thanks! Those always make my head hurt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify your type as covariant (`out`) so subclass types can be included:

```
var tutorialSlides: ArrayList<Class<out TutorialSlideFragment>> = arrayListOf(
        WelcomeFragment::class.java
)
```

Or to make it easier to instantiate them later, you can specify a list of constructors:

```
val tutorialSlides: ArrayList<() -> TutorialSlideFragment> = arrayListOf(
        ::WelcomeFragment
)
```

and call the constructors like any other function:

```
val newFragment = tutorialSlides[0]()
```