# Is it possible to use the instanceof operator in a switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement, instanceof

I have a question of using switch case for `instanceof` object:

For example: my problem can be reproduced in Java:

```
if(this instanceof A)
    doA();
else if(this instanceof B)
    doB();
else if(this instanceof C)
    doC():
```

How would it be implemented using `switch...case`?

Comment: If you really feel you need a switch you could hash the class name to an int and use that, watch out for possible clashes though. Adding as comment rather than an answer as I don't like the idea of this actually been used.  Maybe what you really need is the visitor pattern.

Comment: As of java 7 you could even switch on the fully qualified class name to avoid such hash clashes as @vickirk pointed out, but it's still ugly.

Comment: It is possible with [the classname as an Enum value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55380782/4467208)

Answer (score 270, accepted):

This is a typical scenario where subtype polymorphism helps. Do the following

```
interface I {
  void do();
}

class A implements I { void do() { doA() } ... }
class B implements I { void do() { doB() } ... }
class C implements I { void do() { doC() } ... }
```

Then you can simply call `do()` on `this`.

If you are not free to change `A`, `B`, and `C`, you could apply the visitor pattern to achieve the same.

Comment: Visitor pattern means that A,B and C have to implement an interface with an abstract method that takes a Visitor as an input parameter, what if you cannot change A,B,C and none of them implements that interface?

Comment: The last comment about the visitor pattern is wrong. You would still need to make A,B and C implement an interface.

Comment: @BenThurley You're technically correct. Yet, there is a common (at least for me) modification of the visitor pattern, where you encapsulate the dynamic dispatch into a dispatcher class which contains OP's instanceof cascade. But then, this cascade is at least reusable and separately testable for correctness and completeness (via reflection based unit tests). And you don't have to change the original classes.

Comment: Sadly this does not work if the do()-Code requires the environment of the host (i.e. access to variables not present in the do() itself).

Comment: @mafu OP's question was about type based dispatching. If your do() method needs more input in order to dispatch than your problem is IMHO outside the scope of the question discussed here.

Comment: this answer assumes that you can modify the classes A,B,C, while I think the point is how to do that without modify A,B,C because they might be in a third part library

Comment: Quite late, but like daniele said: yes, this method is useless for checking types in a generic collection for example, where you have a set of objects which you know, can be of some set of types, but you must check which of them it is.

Comment: Downvoted because you cannot use the visitor pattern without modifying the classes A, B, and C.

Comment: If you cannot or don't want to modify A,B,C, you can try using the Decorator pattern to add the required method to those classes and provide the "Element" interface for the Visitor pattern.

Comment: What in case of DTOs? DTO should not have methods...

Comment: 11 years after this anaswer, Java 17 finally allows exactly what the op wants. See answer below on pattern matching  https://stackoverflow.com/a/57432241/731548

Comment: this only works if the behavior is in the class itself, it doesn't work with the behavior in an external class, for that other pattern like template method or facade would be useful

Answer (score 124):

if you absolutely cannot code to an interface, then you could use an enum as an intermediary:

```
public A() {

    CLAZZ z = CLAZZ.valueOf(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    switch (z) {
    case A:
        doA();
        break;
    case B:
        doB();
        break;
    case C:
        doC();
        break;
    }
}


enum CLAZZ {
    A,B,C;

}
```

Comment: thx, I also had to make some changes: 1) initialize each enum id with the Class reference; 2) assert the class simple name with the enum id .toString(); 3)find the enum thru the stored Class reference per enum id. I think this is also obfuscation safe then.

Comment: if this.getClass().getSimpleName() does not match a value of CLAZZ it throwns an Exception... it's better to surround with a try catch block and the Exception would be treated as the "default" or "else" option of the switch

Comment: usually people look toward switch due to performance considerations, and Enum.instanceOf [should not be mentioned here](https://medium.com/javarevisited/micro-optimizations-in-java-good-nice-and-slow-enum-261e6f77bd2e).

Comment: This breaks automatic rename for class names in `case A`, `case B` and `case C` when refactoring with the most used IDEs.

Answer (score 91):

Java now allows you to switch in the manner of the OP. They call it [Pattern Matching](https://openjdk.org/jeps/406) for switch. It was released as a preview feature of Java 17. The example given in the JEP is

```java
    String formatted;
switch (obj) {
    case Integer i : formatted = String.format ( "int %d", i); break;
    case Byte b : formatted = String.format ( "byte %d", b); break;
    case Long l : formatted = String.format ( "long %d", l); break;
    case Double d : formatted = String.format ( "double %f", d); break;
    case String s : formatted = String.format ( "String %s", s); break;
    default: formatted = obj.toString();
}
```

or using their lambda syntax and returning a value

```java
String formatted = switch (obj) {
                      case Integer i -> String.format ( "int %d", i );
                      case Byte b -> String.format ( "byte %d", b );
                      case Long l -> String.format ( "long %d", l );
                      case Double d -> String.format ( "double %f", d );
                      case String s -> String.format ( "String %s", s );
                      default -> obj.toString();
                   };
```

either way they've been doing cool stuff with switches.

Comment: @olidev consider making this the (new) accepted answer.

Comment: This is only in preview mode for Java 17.

Comment: @A_Arnold "This is a preview feature, which is a feature whose design, specification, and implementation are complete, but is not permanent, which means that the feature may exist in a different form or not at all in future Java SE releases." ref: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/pattern-matching-switch-expressions-and-statements.html

Comment: This is a preview only feature in Java 17 whose syntax may change and has to be turned on with a VM parameter.

Comment: Java 21 is available, it's final now and no longer a preview feature.

Answer (score 78):

Create a `Map` where the key is `Class<?>` and the value is an expression (lambda or similar). Consider:

```
Map<Class,Runnable> doByClass = new HashMap<>();
doByClass.put(Foo.class, () -> doAClosure(this));
doByClass.put(Bar.class, this::doBMethod);
doByClass.put(Baz.class, new MyCRunnable());

// of course, refactor this to only initialize once

doByClass.get(getClass()).run();
```

If you need checked exceptions than implement a `FunctionalInterface` that throws the `Exception` and use that instead of `Runnable`.

---

Here's a real-word before-and-after showing how this approach can simplify code.

The code before refactoring to a map:

```java
private Object unmarshall(
  final Property<?> property, final Object configValue ) {
  final Object result;
  final String value = configValue.toString();

  if( property instanceof SimpleDoubleProperty ) {
    result = Double.parseDouble( value );
  }
  else if( property instanceof SimpleFloatProperty ) {
    result = Float.parseFloat( value );
  }
  else if( property instanceof SimpleBooleanProperty ) {
    result = Boolean.parseBoolean( value );
  }
  else if( property instanceof SimpleFileProperty ) {
    result = new File( value );
  }
  else {
    result = value;
  }

  return result;
}
```

The code after refactoring to a map:

```java
private final Map<Class<?>, Function<String, Object>> UNMARSHALL = 
Map.of(
  SimpleBooleanProperty.class, Boolean::parseBoolean,
  SimpleDoubleProperty.class, Double::parseDouble,
  SimpleFloatProperty.class, Float::parseFloat,
  SimpleFileProperty.class, File::new
);

private Object unmarshall(
  final Property<?> property, final Object configValue ) {
  return UNMARSHALL
    .getOrDefault( property.getClass(), ( v ) -> v )
    .apply( configValue.toString() );
}
```

This avoids repetition, eliminates nearly all branching statements, and simplifies maintenance.

Comment: Upvoted; this is one of the few answers that actually helps the OP do what he is asking for (and yes, it's often possible to refactor the code to not have to do `instanceof`, and no, my scenario is unfortunately not one of those that easily fits into that box...)

Comment: @SergioGutiérrez Thanks. Well, this pattern should only be needed with an external library. And even then you can just create an interface with an adapter implementation instead, but it's useful where you want the behavioral DIFF, so to speak, to be more obvious. Similar to fluent vs annotation API routing I suppose.

Comment: This only works for exact matches. `Class<ArrayList>` will not match `Class<List>`.

Comment: It's a good answer to the question, but I don't like the code. It's obscure, and I'd much rather prefer the initial code, albeit it can be put in a separate service you will rarely need to view / touch.

Comment: @html_programmer fair enough, but there is a fine line between "obscure" and "ignorant"  especially regarding functional programming

Comment: @Novaterata I would call the initial code a readable refactor of the second. But to each their own.

Answer (score 41):

Just in case if someone will read it:

The BEST solution in java is :

```
public enum Action { 
    a{
        void doAction(...){
            // some code
        }

    }, 
    b{
        void doAction(...){
            // some code
        }

    }, 
    c{
        void doAction(...){
            // some code
        }

    };

    abstract void doAction (...);
}
```

The GREAT benefits of such pattern are:

1. You just do it like (NO switches at all):

   ```
   void someFunction ( Action action ) {
       action.doAction(...);   
   }
   ```
2. In case if you add new Action called "d" you MUST imlement doAction(...) method

NOTE: This pattern is described in Joshua's Bloch "Effective Java (2nd Edition)"

Comment: nice! Is the `@Override` required above each implementation of `doAction()`?

Comment: How is this the "BEST" solution? How would you decide which `action` to use? By an outer instanceof-cascade that calls `someFunction()` with the correct `action`? This just adds another level of indirection.

Comment: No, it will be done automatically at runtime. If you call someFunction(Action.a) then a.doAction will be called.

Comment: I don't understand this. How would you know which enum to use? As @PureSpider said, this seems like just another level of work to do.

Comment: It is probably case, when you have enum inside appropriate entity already, then you can take it from there...

Comment: Thank you! following yout sugestion, here what I made:
1- Add the enom at the Super Class:
2- Add a abstract getter in Super Class to get the enom;
3- Implemented the abstract enom getter um concrete Class;
4- finished runing the concrete class method.

Comment: This is a very handy, concise way to implement the Abstract Factory Pattern.  Thank you!

Comment: It's very sad that you **did not have offered a complete example**, e.g. how map any Class-Instance of a,b or C to this enum. I'll try to cast the Instance to this Enum.

Answer (score 30):

You can't. The `switch` statement can only contain `case` statements which are compile time constants and which evaluate to an integer (Up to Java 6 and a string in Java 7).

What you are looking for is called "pattern matching" in functional programming.

See also [Avoiding instanceof in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790144/avoiding-instanceof-in-java)

Comment: No, in most functional languages you can't pattern match on types, only on constructors. That is at least true in ML and Haskell. In Scala and OCaml it is possible but not the typical application of pattern matching.

Comment: Sure, but checking against constructors would be "equivalent" to the scenario described above.

Comment: In some cases, but not in general.

Comment: Switches can also support enums.

Answer (score 20):

As discussed in the top answers, the traditional OOP approach is to use polymorphism instead of switch. There is even a well documented refactoring pattern for this trick: [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html). Whenever I reach for this approach, I like to also implement a [Null object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceNullObject.html) to provide the default behaviour.

Starting with Java 8, we can use lambdas and generics to give us something functional programmers are very familiar with: pattern matching. It's not a core language feature but the [VAVR Library](https://www.vavr.io/) - formerly Javaslang library provides one implementation. Example from the docs:

```
Match.ofType(Number.class)
    .caze((Integer i) -> i)
    .caze((String s) -> new BigDecimal(s))
    .orElse(() -> -1)
    .apply(1.0d); // result: -1
```

It's not the most natural paradigm in the Java world so use it with caution. While the generic methods will save you from having to typecast the matched value, we're missing a standard way to decompose the matched object as with [Scala's case classes](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/case-classes.html) for example.

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, it is not possible out of the box since the switch-case statement expects a constant expression. To overcome this, one way would be to use enum values with the class names e.g.

```
public enum MyEnum {
   A(A.class.getName()), 
   B(B.class.getName()),
   C(C.class.getName());

private String refClassname;
private static final Map<String, MyEnum> ENUM_MAP;

MyEnum (String refClassname) {
    this.refClassname = refClassname;
}

static {
    Map<String, MyEnum> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, MyEnum>();
    for (MyEnum instance : MyEnum.values()) {
        map.put(instance.refClassname, instance);
    }
    ENUM_MAP = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}

public static MyEnum get(String name) {
    return ENUM_MAP.get(name);
 }
}
```

With that is is possible to use the switch statement like this

```
MyEnum type = MyEnum.get(clazz.getName());
switch (type) {
case A:
    ... // it's A class
case B:
    ... // it's B class
case C:
    ... // it's C class
}
```

Comment: I believe that until JEP issue 8213076 is fully implemented, this is the cleanest way get a switch statement based on the type, without modifying the target class.

Comment: Since the lookup `Map` is read-only and initialized by one thread only, a simple `HashMap` should be preferred from my point of view.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is very late but for future readers ...

Beware of the approaches above that are based only on the *name* of the class of **A**, **B**, **C** ... :

Unless you can guarantee that **A**, **B**, **C** ... (all subclasses or implementers of **Base**) are **final** then subclasses of **A**, **B**, **C** ... will not be dealt with.

Even though the **if, elseif, elseif ..**  approach is slower for large number of subclasses/implementers, it is more accurate.

Comment: Indeed, you [should never use the polymorphimsm](http://valjok.blogspot.com/2013/01/java-oop-is-sux-from-very-beginning.html) (aka OOP)

Answer (score 10):

java 7+

```
public <T> T process(Object model) {
    switch (model.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
    case "Trade":
        return processTrade((Trade) model);
    case "InsuranceTransaction":
        return processInsuranceTransaction((InsuranceTransaction) model);
    case "CashTransaction":
        return processCashTransaction((CashTransaction) model);
    case "CardTransaction":
        return processCardTransaction((CardTransaction) model);
    case "TransferTransaction":
        return processTransferTransaction((TransferTransaction) model);
    case "ClientAccount":
        return processAccount((ClientAccount) model);
    ...
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(model.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

---

You can be even faster by for omitting string manipulation inside `getSimpleName` by for introducing constants and using full class name:

```
public static final String TRADE = Trade.class.getName();
...
switch (model.getClass().getName()) {
case TRADE:
```

Comment: This is not the same as doing an instanceof, as this only works if the implementation class is used to switch, but it will not work for interfaces/abstractclass/superclasses

Comment: yeah, this is not

Comment: A for effort, but aside from @lifesoordinary's comment, you also miss the typesafety that you normally have, because this answer uses hardcoded strings, instead of class references. It is quite easy to make a typo, especially if you'd need to extend this functionality with full canonical names if here was any overlap in class names with different package names.Edit: fixed typo (which kinda proves my point)

Comment: @RikSchaaf in addition to losing type safety you also lose the possibility of using subclass implementations in the switch. I'd say that this should be avoided.

Comment: I'd say instanceof should be avoided in many [cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596462/any-reason-to-prefer-getclass-over-instanceof-when-generating-equals)

Comment: @Mike agreed for the case of `equals()` implementations, to keep it symmetric. Also in a lot of cases you can rewrite your code to use polymorphism, instead of `instanceof`. There are still some valid use cases though.

Comment: @RikSchaaf, your typo will be revealed by a test, you write unit tests, don't you? Also if you can rewrite you case with polymorphism, then it was 'polymorphism case', which has nothing to do with the question asked. Open `java.awt.Component#process...` methods and show me where you can put your polymorphism there. I personally used hash maps for similar cases, but the question was asked about switch, and I believe there could be performance reasons for that, because even hash map is fast, switch is [faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27993819/hashmap-vs-switch-statement-performance)

Comment: Enum.valueOf seems to be much [worse](https://medium.com/javarevisited/micro-optimizations-in-java-good-nice-and-slow-enum-261e6f77bd2e) from performance point of view and should not be mentioned inline with `switch` and `HashMap`

Answer (score 6):

Nope, there is no way to do this. What you might want to do is however to consider **[Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)** as a way to handle these kind of problems.

Answer (score 5):

You can't a switch only works with the byte, short, char, int, String and enumerated types (and the object versions of the primitives, it also depends on your java version, Strings can be `switch`ed on in java 7)

Comment: You can't switch on Strings in Java 6. And you can't switch on "object versions of the primitives".

Comment: @Bozho I did say it depends on your java version, in Java 7 you can switch on Strings.

Comment: @Lukas Eder check your java spec you can

Answer (score 5):

Using switch statements like this is not the object oriented way. You should instead use the power of *polymorphism*. Simply write

```
this.do()
```

Having previously set up a base class:

```
abstract class Base {
   abstract void do();
   ...
}
```

which is the base class for `A`, `B` and `C`:

```
class A extends Base {
    void do() { this.doA() }
}

class B extends Base {
    void do() { this.doB() }
}

class C extends Base {
    void do() { this.doC() }
}
```

Comment: @jmg suggeests (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579309/switch-instanceof/5579385#5579385) using an interface instead of an abstract base class. That can be superior in some circusmtances.

Answer (score 5):

I personally like the following Java 1.8 code:

```
    mySwitch("YY")
            .myCase("AA", (o) -> {
                System.out.println(o+"aa");
            })
            .myCase("BB", (o) -> {
                System.out.println(o+"bb");
            })
            .myCase("YY", (o) -> {
                System.out.println(o+"yy");
            })
            .myCase("ZZ", (o) -> {
                System.out.println(o+"zz");
            });
```

Will output:

```
YYyy
```

The sample code uses Strings but you can use any object type, including Class. e.g. `.myCase(this.getClass(), (o) -> ...`

Needs the following snippet:

```
public Case mySwitch(Object reference) {
    return new Case(reference);
}

public class Case {

    private Object reference;

    public Case(Object reference) {
        this.reference = reference;
    }

    public Case myCase(Object b, OnMatchDo task) {
        if (reference.equals(b)) {
            task.task(reference);
        }
        return this;
    }
}

public interface OnMatchDo {
    public void task(Object o);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can manipulate the common interface, you could do add in an enum and have each class return a unique value. You won't need instanceof or a visitor pattern.

For me, the logic needed to be in the written in the switch statement, not the object itself. This was my solution:

`ClassA, ClassB, and ClassC implement CommonClass`

Interface:

```
public interface CommonClass {
   MyEnum getEnumType();
}
```

Enum:

```
public enum MyEnum {
  ClassA(0), ClassB(1), ClassC(2);

  private int value;

  private MyEnum(final int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
```

Impl:

```
...
  switch(obj.getEnumType())
  {
    case MyEnum.ClassA:
      ClassA classA = (ClassA) obj;
    break;

    case MyEnum.ClassB:
      ClassB classB = (ClassB) obj;
    break;

    case MyEnum.ClassC:
      ClassC classC = (ClassC) obj;
    break;
  }
...
```

If you are on java 7, you can put string values for the enum and the switch case block will still work.

Comment: The `value` field is redundant if you only want to distinguish the enum constants - you can use the constants directly (as you do).

Answer (score 2):

How about this ?

```
switch (this.name) 
{
  case "A":
    doA();
    break;
  case "B":
    doB();
    break;
  case "C":
    doC();
    break;
  default:
    console.log('Undefined instance');
}
```

Comment: Should point out that this works only on Java 7. And that you have to call `this.getSimpleName()`
Not sure if the poster is confused with JS (yeah, he's using console, hehe).

Comment: This has a problem of falling out of source code referential transparency. That is, your IDE won't be able to mantain the reference integrity. Suppose you want to rename your name. The reflection is evil.

Comment: Not a great idea.  Class names are not unique if you have multiple class loaders.

Comment: Breaks when it comes to code compression (→ ProGuard)

Answer (score 1):

I think there are reasons to use a switch statement. If you are using xText generated Code perhaps. Or another kind of EMF generated classes.

```
instance.getClass().getName();
```

returns a String of the Class Implementation Name. i.e:
    org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreUtil

```
instance.getClass().getSimpleName();
```

returns the simple represenation i.e:
    EcoreUtil

Comment: You can't use it in `switch` as `case` condition because it is not constant value

Answer (score 1):

If you need to "switch" thru the class type of "this" object, this answer is the best https://stackoverflow.com/a/5579385/2078368

But if you need to apply "switch" to any other variable. I would suggest another solution. Define following interface:

```
public interface ClassTypeInterface {
    public String getType();
}
```

Implement this interface in every class you want to "switch". Example:

```
public class A extends Something implements ClassTypeInterface {

    public final static String TYPE = "A";

    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return TYPE;
    }
}
```

After that you can use it in following way:

```
switch (var.getType()) {
    case A.TYPE: {
        break;
    }
    case B.TYPE: {
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

The only thing you should care about - keep the "types" unique across all the classes implementing the ClassTypeInterface. It's not a big problem, because in case of any intersection you receive a compile-time error for the "switch-case" statement.

Comment: Instead of using String for the `TYPE`, you can use an enum and uniqueness is guaranteed (as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19252352/905686)). However, with any of the approaches you will have to refactor in two places when you do a rename.

Comment: @user905686 rename of what? In current example the type "A" is defined inside the Something class to minimize quantity of code. But in real life you obviously should define it outside (in some common place) and there are no any problem with further refactoring.

Comment: I mean renaming the class A. Automatic refactoring might not include the variable `TYPE = "A"` when renaming. Especially if it is outside the corresponding class, one might also forget it when doing it manually. IntelliJ actually also finds the occurrences of the class name in strings or comments but that's just a text search (instead of looking at the syntax tree) and thus includes false positives.

Comment: @user905686 it's just an example, to visualize the idea. Do not use String for type definitions in real project, declare some MyTypes class holder with integer constants (or enum) and use them in the classes implementing ClassTypeInterface.

Answer (score 1):

Create an **Enum** with Class names.

```
public enum ClassNameEnum {
    A, B, C
}
```

Find the *Class name* of the object.
Write a **switch** case over the enum.

```
private void switchByClassType(Object obj) {

        ClassNameEnum className = ClassNameEnum.valueOf(obj.getClass().getSimpleName());

        switch (className) {
            case A:
                doA();
                break;
            case B:
                doB();
                break;
            case C:
                doC();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: In contrast to [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19252352/905686) where the coupling between enum constants and classes is done explicitly, you do the coupling implicitly by class name. This will break your code when you rename only one of the enum constant or the class whereas the other approach would still work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a functional way of accomplishing it in Java 8 using http://www.vavr.io/

```
import static io.vavr.API.*;
import static io.vavr.Predicates.instanceOf;
public Throwable liftRootCause(final Throwable throwable) {
        return Match(throwable).of(
                Case($(instanceOf(CompletionException.class)), Throwable::getCause),
                Case($(instanceOf(ExecutionException.class)), Throwable::getCause),
                Case($(), th -> th)
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While it is not possible to write a switch statement, it is possible to branch out to specific processing for each given type. One way of doing this is to use standard double dispatch mechanism. An example where we want to "switch" based on type is Jersey Exception mapper where we need to map multitude of exceptions to error responses. While for this specific case there is probably a better way (i.e. using a polymorphic method that translates each exception to an error response), using double dispatch mechanism is still useful and practical.

```
interface Processable {
    <R> R process(final Processor<R> processor);
}

interface Processor<R> {
    R process(final A a);
    R process(final B b);
    R process(final C c);
    // for each type of Processable
    ...
}

class A implements Processable {
    // other class logic here

    <R> R process(final Processor<R> processor){
        return processor.process(this);
    }
}

class B implements Processable {
    // other class logic here

    <R> R process(final Processor<R> processor){
        return processor.process(this);
    }
}

class C implements Processable {
    // other class logic here

    <R> R process(final Processor<R> processor){
        return processor.process(this);
    }
}
```

Then where ever the "switch" is needed, you can do it as follows:

```
public class LogProcessor implements Processor<String> {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.for(LogProcessor.class);

    public void logIt(final Processable base) {
        log.info("Logging for type {}", process(base));
    }

    // Processor methods, these are basically the effective "case" statements
    String process(final A a) {
        return "Stringifying A";
    }

    String process(final B b) {
        return "Stringifying B";
    }

    String process(final C c) {
        return "Stringifying C";
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks a lot like the Visitor pattern, which was already discussed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5579385

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Java 17 you can use pattern matching for switch expressions (preview feature) [JEP-406](https://openjdk.org/jeps/406).

```
public void doAction(Object o) {
    return switch (o) {
        case A a -> doA(a);
        case B b -> doB(b);
        case C c -> doC(c);
        default -> log.warn("Unrecognized type of {}", o);
    };
}
```

Guard pattern is also available:

```
public void doAction(Object o) {
    return switch (o) {
        case String s && !s.isBlank() -> handle(s);
    };
}
```

You need to enable preview features to use it: `java --enable-preview`

Comment: This was already answered.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 19 recent release this has been very easy and useful :
Create interface and have method called makesomenoise() which accepts animal parameter.

```
void makeSomeNoise (Animal animal) {
switch (animal) {
case Dog dog → dog.bark();
case Cat catcat.meow();
default throw new RuntimeException ("WTH is it???");
}
}
```

Comment: This was already answered.

Answer (score 0):

there is an even simpler way of emulating a switch structure that uses instanceof, you do this by creating a code block in your method and naming it with a label. Then you use if structures to emulate the case statements. If a case is true then you use the break LABEL_NAME to get out of your makeshift switch structure.

```
        DEFINE_TYPE:
        {
            if (a instanceof x){
                //do something
                break DEFINE_TYPE;
            }
            if (a instanceof y){
               //do something
                break DEFINE_TYPE;
            }
            if (a instanceof z){
                // do something
                break DEFINE_TYPE;
            }
        }
```

Comment: How is this any better than the `if`... `else if` code given by the OP?

Comment: Just to elaborate on my previous comment: what you're proposing is essentially to replace `if`... `else if` with "goto" statements, which is the *wrong* way to implement control flow in languages like Java.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Modelling Framework has an interesting idea that also considers inheritance. The basic concept is defined in the Switch [interface](https://download.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/emf/javadoc/2.9.0/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/Switch.html): switching is done by invoking the *doSwitch* method.

What is really interesting is the implementation. For each type of interest, a

```
public T caseXXXX(XXXX object);
```

method must be implemented (with a default implementation returning null). The *doSwitch* implementation will attempt to call al the *caseXXX* methods on the object for all its type hierarchy. Something in the lines of:

```
BaseType baseType = (BaseType)object;
T result = caseBaseType(eAttribute);
if (result == null) result = caseSuperType1(baseType);
if (result == null) result = caseSuperType2(baseType);
if (result == null) result = caseSuperType3(baseType);
if (result == null) result = caseSuperType4(baseType);
if (result == null) result = defaultCase(object);
return result;
```

The actual framework uses an integer id for each class, so the logic is actually a pure switch:

```
public T doSwitch(Object object) {
    return doSwitch(object.class(), eObject);
}

protected T doSwitch(Class clazz, Object object) {
    return doSwitch(getClassifierID(clazz), object);
}

protected T doSwitch(int classifierID, Object theObject) {
    switch (classifierID) {
    case MyClasses.BASETYPE:
    {
      BaseType baseType = (BaseType)object;
      ...
      return result;
    }
    case MyClasses.TYPE1:
    {
      ...
    }
  ...
```

You can look at a complete implementation of the [ECoreSwitch](https://github.com/eclipse/emf/blob/master/plugins/org.eclipse.emf.ecore/src/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/util/EcoreSwitch.java) to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 21 you can use "Pattern Matching for Switch". See https://openjdk.org/jeps/441. This is no preview feature anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Before we get stable pattern matching for `switch` statement, Java 16/17 could provide limited support with "Pattern Matching for instanceof":

```java
if (req instanceof UserRequest userReq) {
    userReq.doUserStuff();
} else if (req instanceof AdminRequest adminReq) {
    adminReq.doAdminStuff();
}
```

It frees you from extra casting statement.

See https://openjdk.org/jeps/394

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do it more naturally without any modifications like this:

```
switch (true) {
  case X instanceof A:
    // do something;
    break;
  case X instanceof B:
    // do something;
    break;
  default:
    // do something;
    break;
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Doesn't work with Java 17. If it works on a newer version please mention it on the answer.

Answer (score -5):

If you want to avoid the verbosity of `if(){} else if{}`, you may consider switching this single file to [kotlin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kotlin_(programming_language)) and use the switch-like [when expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression) in combination with `is` operator.

In any case [Kotlin and java files can co-exist in a project](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-maven.html#compiling-kotlin-and-java-sources) and result in a jar that can run in JVM.

```kotlin
when (this) { //switch-like statement in kotlin supporting class-pattern-matching and smart casts via `is` operator.
    is A -> doA()
    is B -> doB()
    is C -> doC()
}
```