# HashMap a function which contains ArrayList

Tags: java, hashmap

How can I put the `sheetData` from my function below into a Hashmap?

private static void showExcelData(List sheetData) {

```
for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
  List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
      Cell cell = (Cell) list.get(j);
      if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
      else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
        System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
      else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN)
        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
    }
    if (j < list.size() - 1) {
      System.out.print(", ");
    }
}
  System.out.println("");
}
```

}

The program is reading the data from an excel file!

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

public class readexcel{

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unchecked" })
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

String filename = "C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\test5.xls";


List sheetData = new ArrayList();
FileInputStream fis = null;
try {

fis = new FileInputStream(filename);


HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);

HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
while (rows.hasNext()) {
HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

List data = new ArrayList();
while (cells.hasNext()) {
HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
data.add(cell);
}

sheetData.add(data);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
if (fis != null) {
fis.close();
}
}

showExcelData(sheetData);
}

private static void showExcelData(List sheetData) {

for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
Cell cell = (Cell) list.get(j);
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
} else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
} else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) {
System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
 }
if (j < list.size() - 1) {
System.out.print(", ");
}
}
System.out.println("");
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly, it is very difficult to read otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried something where you use the index of the cell, and map the cell to that? What is contained in a Cell object, what have you tried to do so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/14136721/545127

Comment: Even with the update, I still don't know what is contained inside the cell objects. If it is a custom thing, can't you create an index to map to?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, but I think you are asking how to use the Strategy design pattern, so you use a `Map` rather than `if`..`else if`.

So you need to

1. Write an interface or abstract base class that represents the abstract operation.
2. Write a mapping of types to operations (a `Map` from the cell types to the operations.
3. Alter your `showExcelData` method to use that mapping to find which operation to use, and then delegate to that operation.