# How can we replace switch statement with arrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I got a sample code based on switch statement. I want some how add it in arrayList or HashMap. Also, what do you think which option would be good to use and why?

```
public static final IFeatureExtraction create(final int piFeatureExtractionMethod, IPreprocessing poPreprocessing)
throws FeatureExtractionException
{
    IFeatureExtraction oFeatureExtraction = null;

    switch(piFeatureExtractionMethod)
    {
        case MARF.LPC:
            oFeatureExtraction = new LPC(poPreprocessing);
            break;

        case MARF.FFT:
            oFeatureExtraction = new FFT(poPreprocessing);
            break;

        case MARF.F0:
            oFeatureExtraction = new F0(poPreprocessing);
            break;

        case MARF.SEGMENTATION:
            oFeatureExtraction = new Segmentation(poPreprocessing);
            break;

        case MARF.CEPSTRAL:
            oFeatureExtraction = new Cepstral(poPreprocessing);
            break;

        case MARF.RANDOM_FEATURE_EXTRACTION:
            oFeatureExtraction = new RandomFeatureExtraction(poPreprocessing);
            break;

        case MARF.MIN_MAX_AMPLITUDES:
            oFeatureExtraction = new MinMaxAmplitudes(poPreprocessing);
            break;

        case MARF.FEATURE_EXTRACTION_PLUGIN:
        {
            try
            {
                oFeatureExtraction = (IFeatureExtraction)MARF.getFeatureExtractionPluginClass().newInstance();
                oFeatureExtraction.setPreprocessing(poPreprocessing);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new FeatureExtractionException(e.getMessage(), e);
            }

            break;
        }

        case MARF.FEATURE_EXTRACTION_AGGREGATOR:
        {
            oFeatureExtraction = new FeatureExtractionAggregator(poPreprocessing);
            break;
        }

        default:
        {
            throw new FeatureExtractionException
            (
                "Unknown feature extraction method: " + piFeatureExtractionMethod
            );
        }
    }

    return oFeatureExtraction;
}
```

Do you think can any other pattern be applied to it. Mention the pattern name you recommend. Will appreciate extra implementation ideas.

Comment: How do you plan on using the ArrayList or HashMap?

Comment: I am planning to add the case as item and for value i still have doubts. Thats why i am asking for a bit of guidance.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/14216559/545127

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an interface that returns an IFeatureExtraction instance.  Add instances of that interface to a HashMap using the Integer value as the key of the Map.  Rather than invent your own interface, you could use an existing interface like `javax.inject.Provider`.

```
public interface IFeatureExtractionProvider
{
    public IFeatureExtraction build(IPreprocessing poPreprocessing);
}

private final static Map<Integer, IFeatureExtractionProvider> map;

static
{
    map = new HashMap<Integer, IFeatureExtractionProvider>();
    map.put(MARF.LPC, new IFeatureExtractionProvider() {

        @Override
        public IFeatureExtraction build(IPreprocessing poPreprocessing) {
            return new LPC(poPreprocessing);
        }
    });

    // and so on...
}

public static final IFeatureExtraction create(final int piFeatureExtractionMethod, IPreprocessing poPreprocessing)
        throws FeatureExtractionException
{
    IFeatureExtractionProvider provider = map.get(piFeatureExtractionMethod);

    if (provider == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("no provider for " + piFeatureExtractionMethod);

    return provider.build(poPreprocessing);
}
```

Although you didn't mention Spring or IoC, you did ask for additional ideas... Rather than build the Map of IFeatureExtractionProvider in a static initializer you could combine it with an IoC framework like Spring.  Add a new method to the interface (`public int getType()`).  Have your framework inject all instances of IFeatureExtractionProvider to a setter and then add it to the map based on the value of `getType()`.