# How to convert if-else having Boolean conditions into switch?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I want to convert following if-else loop into Switch case where i want Boolean conditions to be converted.

```
public String getRandomValues(WebElement input) {
        String value;
        if (input.getAttribute("id").equalsIgnoreCase("FIRSTNAME")) {
            value = "User";
        } else if (input.getAttribute("id").equalsIgnoreCase("LASTNAME")) {
            value = "Name";
        } else if (input.getAttribute("id").equalsIgnoreCase("ACCOUNTNUMBER")) {
            value = "0123945486855";
        } else if (input.getAttribute("id").equalsIgnoreCase("EMAIL")) {
            value = "user@domain.com";
        } else if (input.getAttribute("id").equalsIgnoreCase("PHONE")) {
            value = "98287825858";
        } else if (input.getAttribute("id").equalsIgnoreCase("DATE")) {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
            value = dateFormat.format(new Date());
        } else {
            value = "Random Value 123";
        }
        return value;
    }
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: `switch (input.getAttribute("id").toUpperCase()) {  case "FIRSTNAME": ...`

Comment: amazingly all four answers (plus the answer in the comments here) will potentially fail based on Locale. http://mattryall.net/blog/2009/02/the-infamous-turkish-locale-bug

Comment: @Patrick: Apart from this, i want to understand approach to handle conditions like...
`input.getAttribute("id").contains("PHONE")`

Comment: @SameerPatil that's not what switch is for.

Comment: @Patrick: in that case what needs to be used other than if-else ?

Comment: @SameerPatil if-else is what needs to be used in this case. but for more complex situations, where actions and conditions need to be constructed dynamically, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26571487/7098259

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
String id = input.getAttribute("id").toUpperCase();
switch(id) {
    case "FIRSTNAME": 
        // something
        break;
    .....
}
```

Comment: To obtain correct results for locale insensitive strings, use toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH). Otherwise, you fail the Turkey Test

Comment: What if the condition becomes 'contains' instead of 'equalsIgnoreCase' ?

Comment: You'll not be able to use switch in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Switch accepts a `String` as a parameter, so you could do:

```
switch (input.getAttribute("id").toUpperCase())
{
   case "FIRSTNAME":
       value = "User";
       break;
   case "LASTNAME":
       value = "Name";
       break;

   //and so on

   case "DATE":
   {
      // You need braces to declare a local variable in a case
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
      value = dateFormat.format(new Date());
      break;
   }
   default: // the same as your 'else'
       value = "Random Value 123";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getRandomValues(WebElement input) {
        String inputValue = input.getAttribute("id").toUpperCase();
        switch (inputValue) {
            case "FIRSTNAME":
                return "User";

            case "LASTNAME":
                return "Name";

            case "ACCOUNTNUMBER":
                return "0123945486855";

            case "EMAIL":
                return "user@domain.com";

            case "PHONE":
                return "98287825858";

            case "DATE":
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
                return dateFormat.format(new Date());

            default:
                return "Random Value 123";
        }
    }
```