# Java - alternative to many else if statements with instanceof conditions

Tags: java, object, instanceof

I have this messy code that I really want to clean up because it has about 12 else if's and each of these if statements check for the instanceof 2 objects, so something like:
If (parentObj instanceof superclass && parentObj2 instanceof superclass)

Each if statement executes something different, so polymorphism I think won't make it any better. Also because 12 different super classes for this little functionality (most if statements execute 1 liners) would be a bit ridiculous. 
And another reason why polymorphism wouldn't work is because I do not have access to the parent class or the super classes. I know that many instanceof conditions is generally not good to do, even though I never really understood why. The methods that are executed inside each if statement are not of the parent class, but are of the super classes, so that's why I need to check for their types so that I can cast them and execute those methods. 
Any ideas as to how I can clean this up? 
Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of detail, I wrote this on my phone. Anyway below is an example of what I am dealing with. I have looked at the strategy pattern, and my only concern with that was for the same reason that I would have to create many different classes and I felt like creating many different objects just to execute 1 liners all of the time would be a bit wasteful. Also it looks like to me that in a strategy design, I would still have to have the many instanceof checks to know which strategy to execute. Anyway, below is some code :p

```
if (plotBlockState instanceof Sign && UpgradeBlockState instanceof Sign) {
    //do Sign Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof Chest && UpgradeBlockState instanceof Chest) {
    //do Chest Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof Dispenser && UpgradeBlockState instanceof Dispenser) {
    //do Dispenser Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof Furnace && UpgradeBlockState instanceof Furnace) {
    //do Furnace Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof BrewingStand && UpgradeBlockState instanceof BrewingStand) {
    //do Brew Stand Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof Hopper && UpgradeBlockState instanceof Hopper) {
    //do hopper Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof Dropper && UpgradeBlockState instanceof Dropper) {
    //do dropper Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof Beacon && UpgradeBlockState instanceof Beacon) {
    //do beacon Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof CreatureSpawner && UpgradeBlockState instanceof CreatureSpawner) {
    //do spawner Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof NoteBlock && UpgradeBlockState instanceof NoteBlock) {
    //do noteblock Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof Jukebox && UpgradeBlockState instanceof Jukebox) {
    //do jukebox Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof Skull && UpgradeBlockState instanceof Skull) {
    //do skull Stuff
}
else if (plotBlockState instanceof CommandBlock && UpgradeBlockState instanceof CommandBlock) {
    //do commandblock Stuff
}
```

Comment: What about if you post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrate your issue?

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet so that we can better understand your issue?

Comment: I worry how you will handle the case where plotBlockState and UpgradeBlockState have different types.  This kind of code, where you say "but it must be the same type, I know it is the same type" although the compiler cannot see they are the same...usually shows something wrong in the design

Comment: Oh boy, I have great news for you: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `Strategy` pattern seems to suit this down to the ground. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is the link to the wikipedia article, which should be more than enough to get you started, and because you've provided 0 code, I think I won't either.

**But because I'm feeling nice**

Firstly, I would have them implementing a common interface or superclass. This is so you don't *need* to test what type of class they are. Simply have them call the same method.
I know you've said polymorphism is out of the question, but I'm not sure why. And if you don't have access to the super class.. make a common interface.

For example:

```
// Undesirable syntax.
if(obj instanceof Dog)
{
    ((Dog)obj).woof();
}
else if(obj instanceof Cat)
{
    ((Cat)obj).meow();
}
else if(obj instanceof Lion)
{
    ((Lion)obj).roar();
}
```

Now let's define some common interface, `Animal`:

```
public interface Animal
{
    public void speak();
}
```

And now your `instanceof` tree looks like this:

```
public void makeTalk(Animal obj)
{
    obj.speak();
}
```

Comment: I did edit the OP. but the reason I can't do this is because the parent object interface (BlockState) that I am dealing with is not in my control, so that I cannot edit it to make another method declaration to do what I need to do.

Comment: But you can surely make another interface for the classes? It's not desirable, but it's sure as hell better than a mountain of `instanceof` operators.

Comment: I think in this case, you may also need to sprinkle in a dash of the adapter pattern.  If you need to extend a bunch of classes you can't edit, then that's really where you end up anyway.