# Java: How to implement switch on Class?

Tags: java, class, switch-statement

How do I implement the following pseudocode in Java?

```
Object getInstance(Class<?> type)
{
  switch (type)
  {
    case A.class:
      return createA(param1, param2);
    case B.class:
      return createB(param3, param4, param5);
    default:
      throw new AssertionError("Unknown type: " + type);
  }
}
```

I know I can probably implement this using a `Map<Class<?>, Callable<Object>>` (mapping classes to a method that returns an object) but is there a more efficient/readable way to do this?

**UPDATE**: I'm sorry for the misleading pseudo code. I did not mean to imply that the classes have no-arg constructors. Each class is constructed differently. I know if-else works but it is not great from an efficiency point of view. It is O(n).

Comment: `switch` in Java is very limited. You can switch on Strings and numbers, that's it. I'm not sure I'd argue for using the (string) type name as the switch .. which leaves the alternative(s) of switching away from switch.

Comment: @user2864740 - switch on Enums as well. Can't do it on Objects in general though.

Comment: @Chris True, I still group them together with numbers in my head. I blame C# :>

Comment: Have a look here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579309/switch-instanceof

Comment: I don't see the problem with switching on `type.getName()` ::shrug::

Comment: @JetAbe this is different. I'm asking for switch-on-a-class, not switch-on-an-object. I don't even have access to an object of that class.

Comment: @BrianRoach, it works but it's a maintenance nightmare. If a class is renamed, the code will break silently. Refactoring tools handle renaming classes, but not Strings referencing classes. Ideally, the code should follow class renames automatically.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the `Class` object to create a new instance?

```
private static final Set<Class> ALLOWED_CLASSES = 
    new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(A.class, B.class));

Object getInstance(Class<?> type) {
    if (!ALLOWED_CLASSES.contains(type)) {
        throw new AssertionError("Unknown type: " + type);
    }
    return type.newInstance();
}
```

Comment: +1 - with the caveat that this only works if the class has the nullary constructor

Comment: I think this would fail, if it is inner class

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/21130129/14731 (and won't work for the same reason).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `switch`, just use `if`.

```
if (type == A.class) {
    return new A();
} else if (type == B.class) {
    return new B();
} else {
    throw new AssertionError("Unknown type: " + type);
}
```

This way you can also handle more detailed cases in your `if` conditions, like subclasses, or interfaces, etc. It also allows your constructors to optionally contain other arguments (following a factory-like pattern), which becomes harder if you just throw them into a map or use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

If all constructors invoked without parameters,

```
Object getInstance(Class<?> type)  {
  return type.newInstance();
}
```

Otherwise, if the number of variants is small, use `if  statements`,
otherwise use map as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If none of the calls to `new` require parameters, then you can use `newInstance()`. Then we just add some error condition code:

```
private static final List<Class> classes = Arrays.asList(A.class, B.class, ...);

public static Object getInstance(Class<?> type) {
    if (classes.contains(type))
        return type.newInstance();
    throw new AssertionError("Unknown type: " + type);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the misleading pseudocode. I didn't mean to imply that classes have no-arg constructors. Each type has its own construction mechanism (different parameters for different classes). Thanks anyway.