# Multiple instanceof in a if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, instanceof

I have a if statement, with multiple instanceof checks. Example:

```
if (object instanceof Object1) {
    // do something
} else if (object instanceof Object2) {
    // to something else
} else if (object instanceof Object2) {
    // and something else
} ...
```

What would be a more elegant way to solve this if-else-query?

Comment: Do they (Object1/2/3) share same interface?

Comment: Where comes `Object` from? please show more code.

Comment: A more elegant way would be to use inheritance and virtual methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579309/switch-instanceof

Answer (score 4):

the best practice in OOP is to put the logic in the `object` itself and make it implement an interface:

the interface:

```
public interface MyLogic{
    public void doLogic();
}
```

first object:

```
public class Object1 implements MyLogic{
  public void doLogic(){// logic 1 here}
}
```

second object:

```
public class Object2 implements MyLogic{
  public void doLogic(){// logic 2 here}
}
```

and now just move your logic to the objects itself and instead all the `if` statements just use

```
object.doLogic(); // make sure object is from type MyLogic, if not, cast it
```

Comment: The problem is, I am not entitled to change Object1, Object2, etc. It is not possible, that they implement an interface. Is there another solution?

Comment: you can use java refections and create a class with methods derrived from the class name and run them with reflection

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be polymorphism so you can create an Interface and implement it for every Object.

```
interface ObjectToBeImplemented{
 method();
}

class Object1 implements ObjectToBeImplemented{ 
 @Override
 method(){...}
}
class Object2 implements ObjectToBeImplemented{ 
 @Override
 method(){...}
}

class Object3 implements ObjectToBeImplemented{ 
 @Override
 method(){...}
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, i doubt if `Object` is good choice for an interface name (even if it just an example) :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical usage for interfaces. See interfaces as defining the Type of an instance. Therefore, you know that all instance of a certain Type can do a particular task. At that point, you don't really care about the concrete class of the object, you just know it has that particular interfaces available to you to use.

Example :

```
public interface Worker {
     public void doWork();
}

public class Object1 implements Worker {
    public void doWork() {
      // work for this specific object
    }
}

public class Object2 implements Worker {
    public void doWork() {
      // work for this specific object
    }
}

public class Object3 implements Worker {
    public void doWork() {
      // work for this specific object
    }
}
```

Then your if statements would be replaced by

```
obj.doWork();
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels like a missed opportunity for **polymorphism**.

This is where a bunch of classes share the same method signatures as their superclass/interface, so the code that calls it doesn't need to know which type it is.

Without polymorphism:

```
Employee employee = ...;
if(employee instanceof Doctor) {
     salary = calcDoctorSalary(...);
} else if(employee instanceof Nurse) {
     salary = calcNurseSalary(...);
}
```

With polymorphism:

```
Employee employee = ...;
salary = employee.calcSalary(...);
```

The magic goes into the subclasses. `calcSalary()` is abstract in a superclass, or a method signature in an interface:

```
public abstract class Employee {
     public abstract int calcSalary(...);
}
```

... or ...

```
public interface Employee {
    public int calcSalary(...);
}
```

Then the type-dependent logic goes into the subclasses:

```
public class Nurse implements Employee {
    @Override
    public int calcSalary(...) {
         // code specific to nurses goes here.
    }
}
```

Whether to extend a class, or implement an interface, is something you'll learn with experience. Often when one doesn't start with an interface, one regrets it later.