# From If statement to Switch statement in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

Is there anyway to write this piece of `if` statement in `switch` statement in Java?

```
Object obj;
if (obj instanceof Integer){

}

if (obj instanceof Double){

}

....
```

This is just an example. `Integer` of `Double` could be replaced by any other object types

Comment: Could you provide an example please? Many thanks!

Comment: @manouti But that is not the same as `instanceof` which is polymorphic.

Comment: @RealSkeptic You're right. BTW, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579309/switch-instanceof) may help.

Comment: OP: Usually, a chain of `instanceof` conditions is an indication of bad class design. Perhaps you should tell us why you need this so we can suggest a change in the design.

Comment: I think this question has been previously answered: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579309/switch-instanceof

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to write this piece of if statement in switch statement in Java?

Not *reasonably*, no, because the `case` labels in Java have to be constants. (This is true of nearly all languages that have `switch`, JavaScript being a rare exception.) You're probably best off with what you have, but with `if/else` rather than just `if`:

```
if (obj instanceof Integer){
    // ...
}
else if (obj instanceof Double){
    // ...
}
```

**However**, you can sort of do it (as of Java 7 or later), but **only because of the specific classes you're testing for**, which are `final` and so we don't have to worry about subclasses.

```
switch (obj.getClass().getName()) {
    case "java.lang.Integer":
        // ...
        break;
    case "java.lang.Double":
        // ...
        break;
}
```

I **do not recommend that** because it does unnecessary work, and **will not work correctly in the general case** (e.g., if you were testing for interfaces, or classes that could be subclassed).

Comment: Not useful if method returns in if code block

Comment: @user4182277: "If" being the operative word; there's nothing in the question suggesting that it does.

Comment: I meant else isn't necessary here. Mobile keyboard ducks. Anyway author should consider doing some refactoring work.

Answer (score 0):

No. You see, `switch` statements are for comparing many different values of the same type for a match to a certain other value.

A `switch` statement is formed like this:

```
switch (var){
    case 5:
    //var == 5
    break;
    case 10:
    //var == 10
    break;
    default:
    //var is not 5 nor 10
    break;
}
```

Which only allows comparisons to constant values, thus making it useless towards data types. An if statement is a much better choice for this purpose, as the only solution for using a switch statement (getting the instance name and comparing it in that format) would be writing too much extra (and unnecessary) code that is not needed and can more easily be done in another manner.