# java 8 switch case default with break for class type

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I was looking for switch over type for java, and I found a solution here: [Switch over type in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570767/switch-over-type-in-java/37334159#37334159)

But the issue, solution was not really like a `switch` with `break`s, sure this will happen because I loop over `Consumer`s , I want to know a good way to **modify** my current code or **clean alternative** to have something to handle my class type, and **break after handle first match** and the default is to handle the unmatched only ( here it is the parent class `StripeObject`) .

My business is to handle stripe events from [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks), I'm using [stripe-java](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java), so my code now something like this:

```
    public void handleWebHookEvent(Event eventJson) throws CardException, APIException, AuthenticationException, InvalidRequestException, APIConnectionException {
        Stripe.apiKey = configuration.getString(AppConstants.STRIPE_API_KEY);

        // Verify the event by fetching it from Stripe
        Event event = Event.retrieve(eventJson.getId());
        Logger.debug(AppUtils.concatStrings("|-> Event Received: [", event.getId(), "] Type: [", event.getType(), "] Request ID: [", event.getRequest(), "]"));
        handleEventObject(event.getData().getObject());
    }

    private void handleEventObject(StripeObject stripeObject) {
        switchType(stripeObject,
                caze(Customer.class, this::handleEventObject),
                caze(Card.class, this::handleEventObject),
                caze(Charge.class, this::handleEventObject),
                caze(Transfer.class, this::handleEventObject)
                caze(StripeObject.class, object -> Logger.debug(AppUtils.concatStrings("|--> !!! Not Handled StripeObject !!! [", object.toString(), "]")))
        );
    }

    private void handleEventObject(Customer customer) {
        Logger.debug(AppUtils.concatStrings("|--> Customer ID <Description> : [", customer.getId(), " <", customer.getDescription(), ">]"));
    }

    private void handleEventObject(Card card) {
        Logger.debug(AppUtils.concatStrings("|--> Card ID <Brand> : [", card.getId(), " <", card.getBrand(), ">]"));
    }

    private void handleEventObject(Charge charge) {
        Logger.debug(AppUtils.concatStrings("|--> Charge ID <Description , Customer , Amount> : [", charge.getId(), " <", charge.getDescription(), " , ", charge.getCustomer() ," , ", charge.getAmount(), ">]"));
    }

    private void handleEventObject(Transfer transfer) {
        Logger.debug(AppUtils.concatStrings("|--> Transfer ID <Description , Destination , Amount> : [", transfer.getId(), " <", transfer.getDescription(), " , ", transfer.getDestination() ," , ", transfer.getAmount(), ">]"));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <T> void switchType(StripeObject stripeObject, Consumer... consumers) {
        for (Consumer consumer : consumers)
            consumer.accept(stripeObject);
    }

    private static <T> Consumer caze(Class<T> clazz, Consumer<T> consumer) {
        return obj -> Optional.of(obj).filter(clazz::isInstance).map(clazz::cast).ifPresent(consumer);
    }
```

In the current code, if the evnet was Customer as example it will print :

```
|--> Customer ID <Description> ... etc
```

Then

```
|--> !!! Not Handled StripeObject !!! ... etc
```

It must print only the first line, not the second if match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only have to change the methods `switchType` and `caze` to use a `Predicate` instead of a `Consumer`, so the loop can stop at the first match. The rest of the code doesn’t need any change:

```
@SafeVarargs
private static void switchType(StripeObject so, Predicate<Object>... predicates) {
    for(Predicate<Object> predicate : predicates)
        if(predicate.test(so)) return;
}

private static <T> Predicate<Object> caze(Class<T> clazz, Consumer<T> consumer) {
    return obj -> {
        if(clazz.isInstance(obj)) {
            consumer.accept(clazz.cast(obj));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

Note that this still differs from the `switch` semantics, as a `switch` statement precludes ambiguous cases in general. Here, one of the types still could be a subtype of another, so, unlike a `switch` statement, the order of `case` statements does matter then.

If all cases are distinct, this is not an issue.