# How to break out of a loop of Consumers

Tags: java, performance, loops, consumer, branch-prediction

Based on the response given by user @eitan https://stackoverflow.com/a/37334159/11214643, on how to perform readable switch cases for auto casting using lambdas, but also based on user @Al-Mothafar 's question, which I guess is a valid point, to try to interrupt the loop instead of just fail-executing all consumers inside the loop, is there a way to iterate throught all Consumers and break iteration if one of them accepts() the clause?

I was thinking something like this, is there any advantage on doing this?

```
public static <T> void switchType(Object o, @NotNull Consumer... a) {
    AtomicBoolean accepted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    for (Consumer consumer : a) {

//I'm not sure if the andThen() method will only execute if the ifPresent(c) clause of the original consumer (code down below) executes. 
//If the andThen() method always executes regardless of whether the execution of the first accept() materializes or not, then this wont work because it will always be executed.

        consumer.andThen(
                object -> {
                    accepted.set(true);   

                }
        );
        if (accepted.get()) break;
     }
  }
```

Is this branching worst for performance than simply fail-executing all consumers?

The consumer method from @eitan 's answer:

```
public static <T> Consumer caze(Class<T> cls, Consumer<T> c) {
    return obj -> Optional.of(obj).filter(cls::isInstance).map(cls::cast).ifPresent(c);
}
```

Comment: `andThen` returns a new Consumer which must be used in place of the original consumer to have any affect. You're ignoring the new Consumer returned by the `andThen` method. Your action will never be executed

Comment: you should improve your question by describing more clearly what you like to achieve. if you want the `Consumer<?>` to indicate if subsequent consumers should be called, you either can throw an exception to break the loop, or the `Consumer<T>` should be a `Predicate<T>` instead to indicate that via a return value, or the passed object `T` is mutable and the `Consumer` sets a value to `T` that indicates it. so a) exception, b) return value, c) parameter. if you can improve your question, the answer can be more specific

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to break the loop by creating an interface that gave a boolean value, that after performing the Optional validation and Consumer execution, returns whether the value .isPresent(), or not.

```
public class Switch {
    public static <T> void caze(Object o, Caze... a) {
        for (Caze consumer : a) {
            if (consumer.isPresent(o)) break;
        }
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    public interface Caze {
        boolean isPresent(Object obj);
    }

    public static <T> Caze type(Class<T> cls, Consumer<T> c) {
        return obj -> {
            Optional<T> o = Optional.of(obj).filter(cls::isInstance).map(cls::cast);
            o.ifPresent(c);
            return o.isPresent();
        };
    }
}
```

This makes possible for the loop to check if it should or shouldn't break.