# Switch cases for Interfaces

Tags: java, interface, switch-statement, instanceof

Is there a way to decide whether a particular interface is an `instanceof` another interface with a switch statement?

```
 MainInterface inter = //load interface

 switch (inter) {
        case instanceof Interface1:
            Interface1 inter1 = (Interface1) inter;
            //execute methods of inter1
        case instanceof Interface2:
            Interface2 inter2 = (Interface2) inter;
            //execute methods of inter2
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use the instanceof operator in a switch statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579309/is-it-possible-to-use-the-instanceof-operator-in-a-switch-statement)

Comment: Not yet, but it's being considered. There is also the deconstructing `if(obj instanceof Interface1 i1) {` that is being considered and would at least make if / else if less awkward

Comment: no, not directly. you could use an enum value, though, that you calculate from the interface depending on its type.

Comment: @Ivar unfortunately this doesn't help me :(

Comment: @kumesana Yeah thats basically my current solution but it looks ugly and want to put it in a switch statement

Comment: @TryHard Non of the 23 answers?

Comment: You could make a Map<Class<?>, Consumer<Object>> that you fill with the interfaces you're interested in and the actions you want to do for each.

Comment: @güriösä I found that solution before but it seems to be more effort. I guess theres no way to change my implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly, this is not possible, as stated in oracle's documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

> A switch works with the **byte**, **short**, **char**, and **int primitive** data types. It also works with **enumerated types** [...], the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer [...].

Some ways of getting around this would be to either use if-else statements or to implement subtype polymorphism, as Ivar suggested.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do it with switch case statement. You have to use if statements.

```
MainInterface inter = null;

if (inter instanceof Interface1) {
    Interface1 inter1 = (Interface1) inter;
    // execute methods of inter1
} else if (inter instanceof Interface2) {
    Interface2 inter2 = (Interface2) inter;
    // execute methods of inter2
}
```

Comment: Thats my current solution, but a switch would look better