# Java instanceof magic

Tags: java, instanceof

There is such a method:

```
static void test(List<String> list) {
    System.out.println(list);
    if (!(list instanceof ArrayList<String> arrayList)) return;
    System.out.println(list == arrayList);
    arrayList.add("list");
    System.out.println(arrayList);
    System.out.println(list);
}
```

Output:

```
[]
true
[list]
[list]
```

Please explain how this is possible?

How does this code create another object (arrayList) that is available throughout the method?: `list instanceof ArrayList<String> arrayList`

Java 17.

Comment: `list` and `arrayList` refer/point to the same object.

Comment: Explain how what exactly is possible? What is confusing you about that code?

Comment: I understand it. Please explain what is happening in this line: if (!(list instanceof ArrayList<String> arrayList))

Comment: `List` is an interface, `ArrayList` is the implementation.  So `instanceof` is checking if the implementation of `list` is an `ArrayList`.  (The generic type might not matter because of erasure.)

Comment: How does this code create another object (arrayList)?: list instanceof ArrayList<String> arrayList

Comment: Not sure what you mean - that is the syntax.

Comment: Where can I read about this syntax? I see this for the first time

Comment: I'm gonna take a gues here and guess you are asking for an explanation of the new instanceof syntax introduced with java 14: [Pattern Matching for instanceof in Java 14](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/pattern-matching-for-instanceof-in-java-14)

Comment: Pattern Matching for Instanceof releasaed with Java 16: [JEP394](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5579309/is-it-possible-to-use-the-instanceof-operator-in-a-switch-statement/57432241#57432241

Comment: It can be helpful, it's somewhat strange as having a local variable presence.  It doesn't appear correct, in terms of typical Java syntax.  You would think it would only apply to the _if_ statement's scope; similar to _for-loops_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is called *pattern matching* and was introduced in Java 14 (see [JEP 305](https://openjdk.org/jeps/305)) and finalized in Java 16 (see [JEP 394](https://openjdk.org/jeps/394)).

A statement like `if (list instanceof ArrayList<String> a) { ... }` causes the `list` variable to be checked whether it is an instance of the `ArrayList` type, and if it is, then assign its value to `a`. Now `a` is available within the if branch.

Equivalent code without the pattern matching feature would look like something like this:

```java
if (list instanceof ArrayList) {
    ArrayList<String> a = (ArrayList<String>) list;
    // do something with a
}
```

The compiler checks the conditions of the if statement to make sure the pattern matching variable is available in the correct scope. For example, your code contains a negation of the result of the `instanceof` operator (using the `!`):

```java
if (!(list instanceof ArrayList<String> arrayList)) {
    return;
}
// Rest of the code
```

Now the compiler deduces that from the `// Rest of the code` line, `list` *must* be of type `ArrayList<Integer>`, so the variable `arrayList` is in scope from here.

#### More info

- [Pattern Matching on Project Amber](https://openjdk.org/projects/amber/design-notes/patterns/pattern-matching-for-java)