# Instanceof correct usage in java

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

Instance of is considered to be a bad practice in java. But I don't know how to avoid it in such situation.
Let's say I have an abstract class `ArtObject` and there are some subclasses such as `Painting`, `Engraving`, etc. And I have a class `Museum` which contains an `ArrayList` of `ArtObject`s.

For example, I'd like to print information about all `Painting` objects in the `Museum`.

Should I do something like this?:

```
public void printAllPaintingsInfo() {
    for (int i = 0; i < artObjects.size(); i++) {
        if (artObjects.get(i) instanceof Painting) {
            System.out.println(artObjects.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Or a better approach exists?

Comment: and what is artObjects?List ,array or some instance of Iterable?

Comment: @KumarAbhinav: why would that matter in this use of `instanceOf`?

Comment: Why is using instanceof a bad idea?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790144/avoiding-instanceof-in-java

Comment: You could solve it via double-dispatch (eg using the *visitor* pattern).  But it would probably be overkill for this situation.

Comment: Thank you, for all answers, I've learnt a lot of interesting ways to solve this problem. But I think that the most efficient in this case is to use instanceof :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with many language features that are usually frowned upon, it is often tempting to cheat around using them by implementing a mechanism that somehow “fakes” them.  But this doesn't make anything better.  If you *mean* to test the type of an object, then `instanceof` is just the right thing to use.  If you want to avoid it, you'll need to find a way that does not *require* you to find out the (dynamic) type of an object.

One popular pattern to avoid run-time type inspection is using the *visitor* pattern which effectively has the overload resolution and dynamic dispatch machinery do the dirty work.  If your real-world problem is as simple as the museum example you've posted, then this is clearly overkill.  Anyway, here is how it could be done.

For the sake of this example, assume we have `Painting`s and `Drawings`, both derived from `ArtObject`.  We define an abstract visitor type that has a method for each `ArtObject`.  Alternatively, you can only specialize for a few and have a fallback “visit anything” method.

```
public abstract class ArtVisitor {

    public void visit(final Painting painting) {
    }

    public void visit(final Drawing drawing) {
    }

    // public void visit(final ArtObject anything) {
    // }
}
```

I have used an abstract class instead of an interface so I can have empty default implementations of the `visit` methods.

In the `ArtObject` interface (or abstract class, for that matter) we need to add an abstract `takeVisitor` method.

```
public abstract class ArtObject {

    private final String name;

    protected ArtObject(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public abstract void takeVisitor(ArtVisitor visitor);

    @Override
    public final String toString() {
        return String.format("%s (%s)",
                             this.name,
                             this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, we cannot *implement* `ArtObject.takeVisitor` since the `this` pointer would have static type `ArtVisitor`, which would require us to do type introspection which is just what we wanted to avoid.  Instead, we must – and this is the ugliest thing about the visitor pattern – override it in each of our classes.

(If we had added the fallback `ArtVisitor.visit(ArtObject)` method, we could have implemented a generic `takeVisitor` method but we'd still have to override it in our derived classes to make overload resolution based on the type of the `this` pointer work.  In most cases, this would add more confusion (and potential bugs) than benefits.)

```
public final class Painting extends ArtObject {

    public Painting(final String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void takeVisitor(final ArtVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }

    public void aMethodOnlyPaintingsHave() {
        // whatever...
    }
}
```

```
public final class Drawing extends ArtObject {

    public Drawing(final String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void takeVisitor(final ArtVisitor visitor) {
        visitor.visit(this);
    }
}
```

Now we can build the museum in a straight-forward manner.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public final class Museum {

    private final List<ArtObject> artworks;

    public Museum() {
        this.artworks = new ArrayList<ArtObject>();
        artworks.add(new Painting("Mona Lisa"));
        artworks.add(new Drawing("Madame Palmyre with Her Dog"));
        artworks.add(new Painting("The Night Watch"));
    }

    public void printAllWorks() {
        for (final ArtObject work : this.artworks) {
            System.out.println(work);
        }
    }

    public void printAllPaintings() {
        final ArtVisitor paintingsPrinter = new ArtVisitor() {

            @Override
            public void visit(final Painting painting) {
                System.out.println(painting);
                // Note: We don't need any unsafe downcast here!
                painting.aMethodOnlyPaintingsHave();
            }
        };
        for (final ArtObject work : this.artworks) {
            work.takeVisitor(paintingsPrinter);
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Museum myMuseum = new Museum();
        System.out.println("All ArtObjects:\n");
        myMuseum.printAllWorks();
        System.out.println("\n\nAll Paintings:\n");
        myMuseum.printAllPaintings();
    }
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
All ArtObjects:

Mona Lisa (Painting)
Madame Palmyre with Her Dog (Drawing)
The Night Watch (Painting)


All Paintings:

Mona Lisa (Painting)
The Night Watch (Painting)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add a method `isPainting()` to `ArtObject` which is `return false;` by default and override to `return true;` in Painting.

Then you can write

```
public void printAllPaintingsInfo() {
    for (ArtObject ao : artObjects)
        if (ao.isPainting())
            System.out.println(ao);
}
```

Or in Java 8 you can write

```
artObjects.filter(ArtObject::isPainting).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: This is a great solution, if we don't expect to do these kinds of comparisons for each subclass. Otherwise `ArtObject` will get polluted with methods like `isPainting`, `isSculpture`, `isEngraving`, `isModernPainting`, etc.

Comment: You could do it with a single method that returns a type enum. Regardless, this relies on being able to modify the ArtObject classes.

Answer (score 1):

One possible alternative is to keep a type in all `ArtObjects`

```
// Pseudocode
class ArtObject {
  Enum artType = { Painting, Engraving }
}

class Painting implements ArtObject {
  Painting() { artType = Painting }
}

public void printAllPaintingsInfo() {
    for(int i = 0; i < artObjects.size(); i++) {
        if(artObjects.artType == Painting) {
            System.out.println(artObjects.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Another might be to keep a separate `Collection` for all `Painting` objects in addition to the `artObjects` collection.

Comment: That adds a field to every object, which seems inefficient. What if you have a sub-type of `Painting` which is a `PortraitPainting`

Comment: I would submit that adding `isPainting` to `ArtObject` is rather inefficient.

Comment: And it somehow misses the point of why `instanceof` should have been avoided in the first place.  Type fields were useful in C when we had no inheritance.  In Java, the type information is already there in the class.  Why duplicate it?

Comment: @CoryKlein I agree if you expect to have more classes than instances.

Comment: @PeterLawrey And we have no idea what the expectations are of the OP. I'm just giving a couple alternatives to using `instanceof`.

Comment: @5gon12eder True. I didn't look at the question holistically, but rather answered the first couple sentences: "Instance of is considered to be a bad practice in java. But I don't know how to avoid it in such situation."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any problems using instance of. But, if you still don't want to use it, you can create a method indicating the type of ArtObject (e.g. Type.PAINTING, Type.ENGRAVING).

Answer (score 1):

I usually define predicates in the base class, or add an explicit subclass name as
an instance variable.

```
class ArtObject {
```

boolean isPainting() { return(false): }
boolean isEngraving() { return(false); }
}

then in the subclasses, define these methods as true
Alternatively

```
typedef enum typeOfArt { generic, painting, engraving };
```

class ArtObject {
typeOfArt type = TypeOfArt.generic;
}

depending on the complexity of your model, you might avoid creating subclasses
entirely if the clutter caused by switch(type) isn't too great.

Answer (score 1):

What if we do something like this?

```
public abstract class ArtObject{

  //Classes extending this class will need to override and implement this method
  abstract public Type getType();

}


public class Painting extends ArtObject {
    /*
      Other code probably
    */

    @Override
    public Type getType(){
       return Type.Painting;
    }
}

enum Type {
   Painting, Museum;
}

public void printAllPaintingsInfo() {
    for (int i = 0; i < artObjects.size(); i++) {
        if (artObjects.get(i).getType() == Type.Painting) {
            System.out.println(artObjects.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would mean you have to maintain an additional `enum` for typing. How would that be advantageous?

Comment: You can do away with that too and instead return a String or something.

Comment: Anyway he one has to match up with something or the other. Keeping enum would probably be advantageous and clean. That's just my view.