# Best practice to retrieve different types of objects from ArrayList<parentType>

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I make an Android app and i have some UI components which must be put in the groups of an expandable list view. I want each class to extand a parent class and the ArrayList will be of this type. The problem is when i retrieve the objects i don't know how to cast them properly i don't know what type of objects the user put in the list. My idea is to use an ArrayList for each type of object but i wonder if there is a better way.

Comment: And why do you need to cast them? And why would you like to add objects of different types (without the same parent) into a single list? If they have to commen parent, then they should be in different lists. Btw some my suggest to use `instanceof`, [but you should avoid that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790144/avoiding-instanceof-in-java).

Comment: do you need to cast them? why?

Comment: The problem is that if i put multiple lists in the childview of the expandable listview i can't get the correct child position. For example if i put 24 objects and  i have 4 lists of 6 objects each one and i want the 16th objects, this is  in the third list at the 3rd index and this is why i want to use only one list for all objects. Also adding and removing childs becomes more difficult.

Comment: Can you please show use your code, so we know what lists you have and what they store? Please reduce the posted code to the parts that are necessary here ... so don't post the _whole_ code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the type of the object either by using `instanceof` or `isAssignableFrom()` to check for the type before you cast.