# instanceOf vs sameInstance

Tags: java, mockito, hamcrest

I am programming a test class using Mockito. I have a class that has a method to return another class

```
public BuilderClass build(){
     return AnotherClass;
}
```

When I use

```
assertThat(BuilderClass.build(), is(instanceOf(AnotherClass.class)));
```

The test is ok but when I use

```
assertThat(BuilderClass.build(), is(sameInstance(AnotherClass.class)));
```

The test is wrong. So, What is the different between use **instanceOf** or **sameInstance**?

Regards.

Comment: A bit off-topic but please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790144/avoiding-instanceof-in-java When you use multiple instanceof in your code it can be considered as a "smell", the use of reflection can clean this up.

Comment: Thank you for off-topic. I didn't know about this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From javadoc

- Creates a matcher that matches only when the examined object is the same instance as the specified target object.

Ie both pointers link to the same memory location.

```
Foo f1 = new Foo();
Foo f2 = f1;
assertThat(f2, is(sameInstance(f1)));
```

Here is the complete test:

```
public class FooTest {

class Foo {

}

private Foo f1 = new Foo();
private Foo f2 = new Foo();

/**
 * Simply checks that both f1/f2 are instances are of the same class
 */
@Test
public void isInstanceOf() throws Exception {
    assertThat(f1, is(instanceOf(Foo.class)));
    assertThat(f2, is(instanceOf(Foo.class)));
}

@Test
public void notSameInstance() throws Exception {
    assertThat(f2, not(sameInstance(f1)));
}

@Test
public void isSameInstance() throws Exception {
    Foo f3 = f1;
    assertThat(f3, is(sameInstance(f1)));
}
}
```

Comment: It'd be a better answer if you described what both do.

Answer (score 3):

`sameInstance` means that the two operands are references to the same memory location. `instanceOf` tests if the first operand is really an instance (object) of the second operand (class).