# Difference between OnClick() event and OnClickListener?

Tags: android, onclick

I'm always using `onclick()` event in most of my projects. But, I read about `OnClickListener()`. Can anyone tell what's the difference between these two? And which one is best to use in Android application?.

Comment: You have accepted the wrong answer. Sean Owen or userSeven7s is correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How exactly does the android:onClick XML attribute differ from setOnClickListener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistener)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm not sure the question is clear. `View.OnClickListener` is an interface, which defines the `onClick(View)` method. If you have a class which intends to listen for clicks, you should both implement the interface (if not already extending a class that does), and implement this method too. You have to use both; they're not somehow alternatives.

Comment: So sad that there is a voting ring in android that down-votes the right answers :(

Answer (score 26):

`OnClickListener` is the interface you need to implement and can be set to a view in java code.

Lately android added a xml attribute to views called `android:onclick`, that can be used to handle clicks directly in the view's activity without need to implement any interface.

Both function the same way, just that one gets set through java code and the other through xml code.

Answer (score 23):

I am assuming by `onClick` that you use is the one that you defines in XML Layout. These two are alternative that serve same function but implemented differently.

1. The `onClick` with function binding in XML Layout is a binding between onClick and the function that it will call. The function have to have one argument (the `View`) in order for onClick to function.
2. An `OnClickListener` is an interface that any class could implement.  Since it is an interface that any class could implement, this has more flexibility and more complex in its form. Few flexibilities that you could have with `OnClickListener`

   - You could easily swap one listener implementation with another if you need to.
   - An `OnClickListener` enable you to separate the action/behavior of the click event from the `View` that triggers the event. While for simple cases this is not such a big deal, for complex event handling, this could mean better readability and maintainability of the code
   - Since `OnClickListener` is an interface, the class that implements it has flexibilities in determining the instance variables and methods that it needs in order to handle the event. Again, this is not a big deal in simple cases, but for complex cases, we don't want to necessary mix up the variables/methods that related to event handling with the code of the View that triggers the event.

Answer (score 11):

OnClickListener is what waits for someone to actually click, onclick determines what happens when someone clicks

the listener is a class, the onclick is a method, this distinction is not very useful in simple cases, but if you want to be more complicated it becomes more necessary

Answer (score 5):

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do stuff
    }
});
```

**OnClickListener** is an interface and **onClick** is method of **OnClickListener**.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple reasons why you might want to programmatically set an OnClickListener. The first is if you ever want to change the behavior of your button while your app is running. You can point your button at another method entirely, or just disable the button by setting an OnClickListener that doesn't do anything.

When you define a listener using the onClick attribute, the view looks for a method with that name only in its host activity. Programmatically setting an OnClickListener allows you to control a button's behavior from somewhere other than its host activity. This will become very relevant when we learn about Fragments, which are basically mini activities, allowing you to build reusable collections of views with their own lifecycle, which can then be assembled into activities. Fragments always need to use OnClickListeners to control their buttons, since they're not Activities, and won't be searched for listeners defined in onClick.

Answer (score 0):

We use

```
    public void button_onClick_name(View v)
{
-------
}
```

to define a method out of the class.
But To define a component Click event within a class, we use onclick listener.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "OnClickListener" as a guy who is waiting your user to click the button of your app.
Then your guy will execute your method **OnClick()**.

You have to put an id to your button in your xml file, then give it a name in your MainActivity.java file. Then set a click listener to your guy. And add your onClick method.
That's why onClick is bound to the interface View.OnClickListener : 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Example :

```
Button myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // your method...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons why you might want to programmatically set an `OnClickListener`. The first is if you ever want to change the behavior of your button while your app is running. You can point your button at another method entirely, or just disable the button by setting an `OnClickListener` that doesn't do anything.

When you define a listener using the `onClick` attribute, the view looks for a method with that name only in its host activity. Programmatically setting an `OnClickListener` allows you to control a button's behavior from somewhere other than its host activity. This will become very relevant for `Fragments`,  `Fragments` always need to use `OnClickListeners` to control their buttons, since they're not Activities, and won't be searched for listeners defined in `onClick`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `android:onClick="your_method"` attribute in your XML.

**Example:**

```
 <Button
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Click"
  android:onClick="your_method"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

We use `OnClick` in xml and `OnClickListner` in `java` code . Both are use to perform a function.

Answer (score 0):

When we want to add click listener to button in Java code, we use `OnClickListener`.
When we want to add click listener to button in the layout file, we use`android:onClick="your_method"`
If you use XML variant, you must implement `your_method` in your app class.

Answer (score 0):

everyone has mentioned about `OnClickListener` listner which one always used.
i want to add one more point `android:onClick` works as method and it's doesn't need to be reference so it's useful when you have to add button after some task executed so you cant't referenced it for `OnClickListener`.

For an `example` when we create viewpager with only layout (no fragments) if you put an button in any layout it insialized only when layout visible so you can't use method `findViewById` for Button in that case `android:onClick` becomed useful just put that method in activity!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple terminology 
If u are at home and U want to call someone..u can call directly and they can listen u. (use onclick). But if u are outside and u want to Call someone at home u need to use either phone or Internet.(need to use onclicklistener).
In Android everything starts from home, I.e. main_activity 
This is the way android eases yr work ; when u have one activity u don't have to attach a listener,  create object, and define it. Just use onClick. 
Onclicklistener are generally used in Fragments. 
So Keep Coding.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple reasons why you might want to programmatically set an `OnClickListener`. The first is if you ever want to change the behavior of your button while your app is running. You can point your button at another method entirely, or just disable the button by setting an `OnClickListener` that doesn't do anything.

When you define a listener using the `onClick` attribute, the view looks for a method with that name only in its host activity. Programmatically setting an `OnClickListener` allows you to control a button's behavior from somewhere other than its host activity. This will become very relevant when we talk about Fragments, which are basically mini activities, allowing you to build reusable collections of views with their own lifecycle, which can then be assembled into activities. Fragments always need to use `OnClickListeners` to control their buttons, since they're not Activities, and won't be searched for listeners defined in `onClick`.

Answer (score -1):

The main diffrence between `onclick()` and `setOnClicklisner()` is discribed as follow:

1. `onclick()`
   Is a attribute in xml. when a button is clicked `onclick` method is called suppose you have three button in layout you can add only one function of `onclick()` and when any of one button will clicked `onclick()` will called
2. `setOnClicklistner()`
   Suppose you have three button in layout you want to perform different action from them. Then you should use `setonClicklistner()` method on each of button to give different method for them