# Gradle: No resource identifier found for attribute 'android.onClick' in package 'android

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I just installed the new Android Studio and am having some trouble as I follow the android developer training guide (http://developer.android.com/training/index.html).

Each time I try to compile my code, I receive this error
"Gradle: No resource identifier found for attribute 'android.onClick' in package 'android'"

My initial search resulted in me checking my API level and capitalization of onClick (neither of which seem to be the issue) ((I also understand that using onClick is not best practice, but I am simply following the guide at this point))
Since receiving this error, I have tried manually reinstalling gradle.
Does anyone know what my issue is?

Also, code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="horizontal" >
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:hint="@+string/edit_message" />
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:android.onClick="sendMessage" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change this  `android:android.onClick="sendMessage"`  to `android:onclick="sendMessage"`

Comment: Pragnani comment should solve this problem. BTW, IMO, its better to add onClick listener on code.

Comment: I have tried "android:onclick" and a few other permutations of the syntax, but have had no luck.

Comment: Try `android:onClick` see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to add button click listeners this way.

[Button Click Listeners in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977212/button-click-listeners-in-android)

Check this out for more details. you can find plenty of resources on how to add buttons.

Generally i find it a good practice to add them through code as opposed to XML

Answer (score 0):

try android:onClick="sendMessage"

In Activity, implement method public void sendMessage(View view);

You should add id to your view widget, and identify these views by id.

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with DArkO. I had the same issue with Android Studio. When I use OnClickListener on my code, the issue has gone away.

On Activity.xml

```
<Button android:id="@+id/message_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        />
```

On Activity.java

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.message_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendMessage();
            }
});
```