# Calling an android java class that calls a canvas from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I'm trying to create an Android project that has a class called MainActivity that's connected to a layout with a start and exit button. The start button is supposed to execute code to call another class that calls a canvas but I always get an error when I call it with an intent.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void startbtn(View v){
    Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),CanvasCall.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

It's supposed to call CanvasCall which has this code:

```
public class CanvasCall extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new MyCanvas2(this));
}   }
```

However, pressing the start button results in a force close. Setting CanvasCall to be the activity when the app starts doesn't result in an error though, but I need the user to be able to choose between "start" and "exit." Help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the crash details?

Comment: Can you share the `onClick` attribute from XML?

Comment: android:onClick="startbtn" is the onClick for the start button. For some reason it doesn't work. I've already updated the Manifest and everything.

Comment: Can you then share the crash details?

Comment: This is what I found in the Logcat. "Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: startbtn" which doesn't make much sense to me since it's already defined in my coding.

Answer (score 0):

There is a debate on whether it's best to use onClick attribute or set the thing programatically. I would go for latter options, here's a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18267474/1051783) on this question.

So remove `onClick` attribute and add an `onClickListener` after `setContentView(...)`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_next).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CanvasCall.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
}
```