# Checkbox inside the Fragment - capturing checks/unchecks

Tags: android, checkbox, android-fragments

I'm trying to recieve checkbox choices inside my Fragment class, however I'm not able to use the way I've used in Activities (calling `android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"` method from a `layout.xml`), because I get the "method onCheckboxClicked not found" everytime this method is called.

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    // Is the view now checked?
    boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

    // Check which checkbox was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case (R.id.checkBox_wifi):
            if (checked)    {
                editor.putBoolean("wifi_on_off", true);
            }
            else    {
                editor.putBoolean("wifi_on_off", false);
            }
            break;

    }

    editor.apply();
}
```

So, I've implemented the View.OnClickListener, but this doesn't get any checkbox checks/unchecks:

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.checkBox_wifi:
            boolean checked = ((CheckBox) view).isChecked();

            if (checked) {
                editor.putBoolean("wifi_on_off", true);
            } else {
                editor.putBoolean("wifi_on_off", false);
            }

            editor.apply();
            break;

    }
}
```

Comment: The implementations are found in fragment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container,false);

    CheckBox checkboxvariable=(CheckBox)rootView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxid);

    checkboxvariable.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(v.isChecked()){ //do this}
            else { //do this }

        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

> checkboxvariable.setOnClickListener(this.getActivity());

inside onClick you can get the resource id, R.id.checkboxid.

Answer (score 2):

Any `onClick` XML attribute will mean that **the method must be found in the activity**, not in the fragment, not in the View. So the way I see it, you have two options:

1. Add the method in the Activity and inside the implementation try to find the fragment and if found, delegate the call to the fragment.
2. Remove the XML `onClick` and rely on `OnClickListeners` that you define in Java code. This subject was already discussed in [at least this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18267288/1051783).

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    CheckBox myCheckBox;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        rootView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_fragment_layout, container, false);
        ...
        ...
        initViews();
        return rootView;
    }

    private void initViews() {
        myCheckBox = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_check_box);
        myCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked)
                    Log.d("TAG=>isChecked", "True");//replace your own stuffs here
                else
                    Log.d("TAG=>isChecked", "false");//replace your own stuffs here
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can set this listener for n number of checkbox!!!

Comment: I know this is old, but thanks. The other methods didn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use your custom Listener

> CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener

inside any other view then *Activity*. Below code sample

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{

  public View onCreateView(...){
    ...
    CheckBox cbFilter = (CheckBox) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chb_rt_is_filter);
    cbFilter.setOnCheckedChangeListener(myCheckboxListener);
    return rootView;
  }

   private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener myCheckboxListener = new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()){
            case R.id.chb_rt_is_filter:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};
}
```