# Cannot hide Android soft keyboard even with inputmanager

Tags: android, keyboard

**Problem:**

> I want to hide the keyboard when the button "Add" is pressed. There are two `EditText` on the screen. The keyboard doesn't appear at starting the activity, which is good, but it doesn't go away on clicking button.

[image]

Here are all the possible questions from Stack Overflow that I have seen whose answers don't help me:

[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

[Programmatically Hide/Show Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7200281/programatically-hide-show-android-soft-keyboard)

[How to hide Soft Keyboard when activity starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977187/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-when-activity-starts)

[How to hide soft keyboard on android after clicking outside EditText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165414/how-to-hide-soft-keyboard-on-android-after-clicking-outside-edittext)

and many others.

Here is my code:

**AddActivity**

```
public class AddActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
EditText text1,text2;
DbHelper db;
ListView l;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);
    db = new DbHelper(this);
    l = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listInAddActivity);
    text1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.i1);
    text2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.i2);
//        text1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
  //      text2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    hideKeyboard();

    loadDataInAdd();

}
public void addNewTask(View view) {
    String s1 = text1.getText().toString();
    String s2 = text2.getText().toString();
    db.addData(s1,s2);
    loadDataInAdd();
    hideKeyboard();
}
public void loadDataInAdd()
{
    try {
        Cursor cursor = db.fetchData();

        ListAdapter myAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.tasks,
                cursor,
                new String[]{db._ID, db.COLUMN_1, db.COLUMN_2},
                new int[]{R.id.idnum, R.id.c1, R.id.c2}, 0);
        l.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  //  MainActivity.loadData();
}
private void hideKeyboard() {
    // Check if no view has focus:
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}

}
```

Most answers are about the `InputManager` method, but it does not work for me, i.e., does not hide the keyboard when clicking on the button. Here is another variation of `InputManager` I used:

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

I also tried this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
);
```

and this does not work either (keyboard isn't hidden on clicking button).

I have also tried:

```
     <activity android:name=".AddActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">

    </activity>
```

and

```
   <activity android:name=".AddActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden">

    </activity>
```

With this one, my app stopped working:

```
   InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

This one totally hid the keyboard (the keyboard did not appear even when the `editText` was clicked):

```
text1.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
text2.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I decided to use an `onclicklistener` for my button, instead of using another function and calling it via `onClick` in `AddActivity.xml`.

I was halfway through my question when I decided to try using `OnCliCkListener` once again. After several random tries, the following is the final code that works for me:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

        }
    });
```

Another way is to use `OnClickListener` in the following manner:

```
    private View.OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do something when the button is clicked

        //public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
            } 
 catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
};
```

Important points for beginners like me:

- The above code should be placed before `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`
- To call the above, place this code in `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`:

  btn.setOnClickListener(mListener);
- Use `try-catch` for exception handling in both methods (`onClickListener`, `setOnClickListener`)

Upon searching for why `onClick`, the `XML` attribute doesn't work for me, while `OnClickListener` does, I have found the following links useful:

[setOnclickListener vs OnClickListener vs View.OnClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479647/setonclicklistener-vs-onclicklistener-vs-view-onclicklistener)

[Android onClick in XML vs. OnClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319996/android-onclick-in-xml-vs-onclicklistener)

[How exactly does the android:onClick XML attribute differ from setOnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene)

[Difference between OnClick() event and OnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453299/difference-between-onclick-event-and-onclicklistener)

Now, halfway through my answer, I realized my mistake in using the `onClick` from XML. Here is what I did to get rid of the `OnClickListener`s:

- First, I moved the part of my code which hid the keyboard into the method in `onClick`. Here in my case, I moved the entire code inside `hideKeyboard()` to `addNewTask`.

Some important points regarding using `onClick`

- The method should be `public` and `void`.
- It should take a `View` parameter, such as `View V`.

Finally, the code that works:

```
  public void addNewTask(View view) {
    String s1 = text1.getText().toString();
    String s2 = text2.getText().toString();
    db.addData(s1, s2);
    loadDataInAdd();
  //  hideKeyboard(); below is the code to hide keyboard
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

---

**Summary**

I found 3 ways to hide soft keyboard for my case, using:

- OnClickListener :

  ```
  private View.OnClickListener mListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(View v) {
      // do something when the button is clicked

      //public void onClick(View v) {

          try {
              InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
              inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
          } 

     catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
          }

  }
  };
  ```
- setOnClickListener:

  ```
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


      public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
              inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

      }
  });
  ```
- onClick, the `XML` attribute:

  ```
  public void addNewTask(View view) {
  String s1 = text1.getText().toString();
  String s2 = text2.getText().toString();
  db.addData(s1, s2);
  loadDataInAdd();
  //  hideKeyboard();
  if (view != null) {
      InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
      inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
  }
  }
  ```

Comment: I appreciated your answer. but all the answer already available. If you doing better search on _Google_. but it's ok all are together.

Comment: @MD: You may be right, since I am a beginner in Android, all the partial answers confused me a lot. In the past few days, I had gone through hundreds of links (most from SO), and tried to implement all of the answers. But they just did not fit together for my case. For example, `InputMethodManager` was the way to go, and almost all answers suggested that, but you can see how in my question it failed. I had to piece together a part from this answer, a part from that answer, a part of my own logic as to where should what code go, and so on.

Comment: Ya that's why i wrote `appreciated your answer`. +1 up

Answer (score 2):

this will help you to hide your keyboard on startup until you touch the edit text.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN
    );
```

in your case, try this

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
             getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); 

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
if (view != null) {  
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

[Close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard?rq=1)