# Support to setup onclick method for my login button

Tags: java, android

I'm brand new to this whole android coding and im trying to setup a login page for my app. I created the login button and im trying to setup the onClick thing for it but its not working. Ill paste my java file below

```
package com.example.user_000.appname;

import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;


public class onClick {

    EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    EditText password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

    public void login(View view){
        if(username.getText().toString().equals("admin") && password.getText().toString().equals("admin")){
            //correcct password
        } else {
            //wrong password
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: not gonna lie, you are missing a LOT of things in here man

Comment: I recommend you take a look at these two tutorials, the concepts will help you out a lot. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html, https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Answer (score 0):

I am not changing anything in your code just i am providing you a way to get it correctly as you are missing lot of things

Button's onClick() method can be set up basically in 3 ways

Very first from xml side when you declare a button

```
<Button
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Login"
android:onClick="login"/>
```

And then just make a method in associated java class with the same name as given in XML file like this

```
public void login(View v)
{
   //do whatever you want here
}
```

Second way you can make an inner implementation anywhere in your class by simply making `onClickListner()` on Button,but you have to make sure to get button on java side by `findViewById()` method once you got it then you can set like this

```
 Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do stuff here
            }
        });
```

third way is also simple you can implement OnClickListner in your whole class and then you can use it for multiple views clicks but i would say if you have a button only then no need to use this you can use above two methods in this one you can do this

```
b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

It will show you an error that methods are not implemented and then you can just use **Alt + Enter** and `onClick()` method will be implemented

```
 @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.yourId) {
            //do stuff here
        }
    }
```

Some useful links are below

[Best practice for defining button events in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6372104/best-practice-for-defining-button-events-in-android?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Difference between OnClick() event and OnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7453299/difference-between-onclick-event-and-onclicklistener)

[Button Click Listeners in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8977212/button-click-listeners-in-android)