# "sayHello(View v)" method in Android "Using a Messenger" Example

Tags: android, android-service

I was trying to understand the "Using Messenger" in [Bound Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) example in Android Documentation. The example had a method named **sayHello(View v)**. I could not quite understand how the method is called and why it takes a view as a argument.

I hope the question can be useful to others and community will take the question positively.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define an 'android:onClick="method"' in layout.xml

This calls the method with parameter "View" of your activity

You may check this QA, too

[How exactly does the android:onClick XML attribute differ from setOnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene)

Comment: Is this a bug in Android Documentation?. Can we report it for greater good of community?

Comment: this functionality has problem, it does not work (yet) with fragments. So I guess google will keep this quiet until solved for fragments, too