# How to quit an application programmatically through button click

Tags: android

I want to quit application through button click.

the code for button click is

```
quitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View paramView) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```

But it require two clicks to exit from the app.

Comment: Is this button in your second activity.?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

use this code...i hope this will help you..

```
  quitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
        @Override
        public void onClick(View paramView) 
      {
            finish();          
            moveTaskToBack(true);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 10):

use this it is work for me:

```
quitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View paramView) {

                moveTaskToBack(true); 
                MainActivity.this.finish();
            }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is `finishAffinity();` to close every active activity.

```
quitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View paramView) {
        finishAffinity();
    }});
```

Answer (score 2):

the app must be quit in the first activity (MainActivity) in the stack (usually the first activity which is lauched when the app starts).
I'm using this code:

```
finish();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

both lines are important. Only killing is not sufficiant since Android may start your app again automatically, therefore finish() must also be used.

If you want to quit your app from another activity, first go back to the MainActivity and quit it from there.
To go back I use this code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
context.startActivity(i);
```

This will call onCreate of the MainActivity. Using a static variable (in the application context) I set a flag if I want to quit in onCreate or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it might help you.

```
quitBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Edit the manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".HomeActivity" android:label="@string/app_title_home" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" />
```

Comment: using this your app will start from last stage (not main activity) from recent app

Comment: Where i have to put this inside button Action??

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid all these confusions if you just had given the `onClick()` function in your xml file. It will handle the `View.OnClickListener()`

Read below link for more information on how is XML implementation different from  `View.OnClickListener()`

[How exactly does the android:onClick XML attribute differ from setOnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene)

Answer (score 0):

> To finish an activity or exit the app

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
    }
```