# where is the correct place to put onclick listeners in android Activity?

Tags: android, onclick, position, oncreate

where is the best place to put onclick listeners in android activity?  I have seen two different ways.  one way is to put them inside the onCreate method, and another way is to put them below and outside the onCreate method.

I just started a new android app and am confused on where is the best place.

both ways are shown below.

psudo code example one;

onclick method inside of oncreate method

```
 MainActivity extends Activity{

 onCreate(){

 onClick listeners 

  } // end of onCreate method

 }  // end of MainActivity class
```

psudo code example two;

putting onclick below and outside oncreate method

```
 MainActivity extends Activity{

 onCreate(){

 } // end of onCreate method

 onClick listeners

 }  // end of MainActivity class
```

Comment: This question is constructive for me.

Comment: Five Ways to Wire Up an Event Listener: http://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam?recipeId=2359

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both way are correct. How you organize the code is actually for readability's sake. If you have too many listeners in `onCreate()`, it's harder to read the code through afterwards. However, if you just have one and it's one liner, it's good to put it in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

you can even put `onClicklistener` using xml file.

i.e

in your xml use this tag:

`android:onClick="startActivityB"`

then in java file

```
public void startActivityB(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: is this bad practice? When would you not do this?

Answer (score 0):

Its upto you how you want to write the code of your activity. 
If you want you can write all the code of onclick in `onCreate()` ,But if you are having more buttons or views to handle and you will write separate onClick for each buttons or views then your `onCreate()` will look so clumsy .

In this situation you can create the common `onClickListener` for your all the buttons and write the logic separately which makes your code look beautiful else you can go for `onCreate()` also.

This is the best way for me:

> ```
>    btn1.setOnClickListener(m_onClickListener);
> /**
>  * Common click listener
>  */
> OnClickListener m_onClickListener=new OnClickListener()
> {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View p_v)
>     {
>         switch(p_v.getId())
>         {
>             case R.id.btn1:
>                 break;
>                     }
>             }
>       };
> ```

Comment: Why i did not allow your `Activity` class implement `OnClickListener`? This will reduce objects count, and easier to read

Answer (score 0):

You can use both the ways . i think the work with same momentum

if use the second method Readability of code will be good

Note : There is also  another approach giving  `onClick` in side your_layout.xml .But now a days fragments came to play it's role so its not used widely ([REFER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4153842/1450401)).

Comment: the 2nd link is dead

Answer (score -3):

You should always prefer the second one. If you place it in on create, it will work too. But you do not want it to be done every time your activity is loaded.

Here is an example

```
package com.damon86.toastExample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ToastExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    // The text and button used on the display.
    EditText toastText = null;
    Button showToast = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a new Layout.
        LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());

        // Create textfield
        toastText = new EditText(getApplicationContext());
        toastText.setText("Hello Toast!");

        // Create button and set OnClickListener
        showToast = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        showToast.setText("Show Toast");
        showToast.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Add components to the Layout.
        rootLayout.addView(toastText);
        rootLayout.addView(showToast);

        // Add the layout as the content view for the application.
        setContentView(rootLayout);
    }

    /**
     * Implemented method - onClick.
     * Show the user a piece of toast.
     */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Create a piece of toast.
        Toast pieceToast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastText.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

        // Show the toast.
        pieceToast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: *it to be done every time your activity is loaded* - this is incorrect.

Comment: @Jin35 The onCreate is called when the activity loads. How am i not clear?

Comment: `onCreate` calls from constructor of activity. In both cases creating an object and calling `setOnClickListener` happens only one time. When user returns to this activity `onCreate` method does not called. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: @Jin35 is not called* :P

Comment: @Jin35 learn to frame your answers ! the crux of SO! facepalm