# android:onClick xml not executing

Tags: android, xml, onclick, label, onclicklistener

I am trying to make a simple application with one layout and two buttons which are going to change the layout text. But I cant find a solution to why the android:onClick doesn't execute. And after trying with an OnClickListener which didn't work but as they did here: [How exactly does the android:onClick XML attribute differ from setOnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene)

I have read and followed the tutorial in the ANdroid SDK website here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

This is my XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/maintext"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.00"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1"  />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button2"  />
```

Here is my Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    TextView label1;
int stage;
Button button1, button2;


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    label1 = new TextView(this);
    TextView label1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maintext);

    stage = 1;
    label1.setText("hello " + stage);
    Log.d("HiThereActivity", "THIS IS DEBUG OUTPUT TO LOGCAT"); //working

    button1 = new Button(this);
    button2 = new Button(this);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button1_click(v);
            Log.d("button1 working", "THIS IS DEBUG OUTPUT TO LOGCAT"); //not appearing
        }
    });
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2_click(v);
            Log.d("button2 working", "THIS IS DEBUG OUTPUT TO LOGCAT"); //not appearing
        }
    });
}

public void button1_click(View v) {

    stage = 2;
    label1.setText("hello " + stage);
    Log.d("b1click", "THIS IS DEBUG OUTPUT TO LOGCAT"); //not appearing

}

public void button2_click(View v) {

    stage = 3;
    label1.setText("hello " + stage);
    Log.d("b2click", "THIS IS DEBUG OUTPUT TO LOGCAT"); //not appearing
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("wrong method", "THIS IS DEBUG OUTPUT TO LOGCAT"); // not appearing
}}
```

So the only Logcat message i get is the one in the OnCreate method. The stage variable always stays at 1 and doesn't change when i click at the buttons. The buttons however animates the click so it must be either the OnClick or the label itself which is not working.

Image of the emulator running: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioUoD.png

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the buttons your are clicking, actually do not refer to those defined in XML layout file.
With this declaration:

```
button1 = new Button(this);
```

you create a new button, but don't refer to those declared in XML layout.

The correct way is to get a reference to button declared in XML layout:

```
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

Comment: Oh thank you! Didn't think about that since I'm pretty new to xml :)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use

```
Button button1 = new Button(this);
```

as that creates a new button, rather than tying it to the button you added to your XML. Instead, use

```
Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Similarly for `button2`.

Answer (score 1):

problem is in here

```
    button1 = new Button(this);
    button2 = new Button(this);
```

instead of using existing buttons you are creating new ones. use like

```
    button1 = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
```

**An additional info**

no need to implement onClickListener here. you are already setting the listeners separately. So it is not needed here

**Some More Info**

It seems you are new to use `onClickListener`. here are different ways of using this.

1. use annonymouse inner class in `setOnClickLIstener` method like you did

   button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       button1_click(v);
       Log.d("button1 working", "THIS IS DEBUG OUTPUT TO LOGCAT"); //not appearing
   }
   ```

   });
2. Implement `OnClickListener` and override `onClick` method. but in that case don't forget to set the listener like

   ```
   button.setOncliClistener(this);
   ```

or if you use another class for listener use like

```
     button.setOnclickListener(thatclass);
```

1. my favourite way is. use `android:onClick` method in xml layout and declare the method like following

   `android:onClick="onClick"`

in class

```
    public void onClick(View v){
        // do your tasks
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the information! Yes I'm pretty new to most methods in Java. I'll try to stick with the android:onClick for now though :)