# setOnClickListener syntax error

Tags: java, android, syntax-error

I am new here, so I apologise if this question is somewhat trivial!

I'm trying to set up a clickable `ImageView` to link to a website, and am getting a syntax error on my `setOnClickListener`, which I can't figure out. I'm sure it's a straight forward error, but if someone could just point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code below:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
    ImageView blipImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.videoBlip);
    blipImg.setOnClickListener = (new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
             Intent intent = new Intent();
             intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
             intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://blip.tv"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: remove the = before the (new View.OnClickListener

Comment: You can also define the onclicklistener in xml. Here's an example [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
  blipImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ // remove =
```

and add @Override annotation

```
blipImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://blip.tv"));
        startActivity(intent);
        }
   });
```

And move the code to `onCreate` as below

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
ImageView blipImg;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
   blipImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.videoBlip);
   blipImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://blip.tv"));
        startActivity(intent);
        }
   });
 }
}
```

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, and it's removed the error . Thanks a bunch for this!

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be in a method body e.g. `onCreate()` and not in class body.

Also remove the `=` after `setOnClickListener`.

Example:

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    setContentView(R.layout.some_layout_that_contains_videoBlip);

    ImageView blipImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.videoBlip);
    blipImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
      public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://blip.tv"));
        startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
blipImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://blip.tv"));
    startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this 
"=" sign will not come in setonclicklistener

```
    public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
ImageView blipImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.videoBlip);
blipImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://blip.tv"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
blipImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://blip.tv"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside `onCreate` method. And `setcontentview` and then do these steps. Because a java class should have only variables and methods, All definitions should be inside a method.

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.your_layout); //your layout which contains imageview with id R.id.videoBlip
   ImageView blipImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.videoBlip);
   blipImg.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){ //remove = symbol
      public void onClick(View v){
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
         intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://blip.tv"));
         startActivity(intent);
      } 
   });
}
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

please remove"=" in your code
and try this

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
super.onCreate(savedInstance);

setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);

ImageView blipImg = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.videoBlip);
blipImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://blip.tv"));
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

}
}