# Android Application Stopped Unexpactedly When Button Click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm new at android developing. I'm trying to make my first application with buttons and toast messages.

I created a button and function for toast message. When i clicked the button, it says "The Application has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again". I have no idea what can i do. Any suggestions? Thanks.

<--------------------------My Activity_main.xml---------------------->

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/start_game"
    android:onClick="startGame" />
```

<------------------My MainActivity.java-------------------->

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void startGame(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the method startGame() to this:

```
public void startGame(View v){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Whenever you use an `onClick` attribute, the corresponding method should be defined with the `View` parameter

Answer (score 1):

If you use `onClick` attribute of the view in xml, then the corresponding java function should be in the form of: `public void (View target)`. It should have a View parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about what you can do - when an application stops like this there's usually more information about what caused it given in a stack trace. This tells you exactly where the program had a problem, in terms of the line number in your code. The stack trace is shown in the Logcat view of your IDE (I presume you're using ADT).

You have the facility to run the application in debug mode, and set breakpoints in the code which allows you to trace through the execution path, and examine the values of variables.

Answer (score 0):

It'd be helpful if you could post the stack trace (I'm not on a computer with Android currently).  But, most likely it's because of your onClick method signature.  Apparently, it needs a parameter of type view

`public void startGame(View v)`

ref: [How exactly does the android:onClick XML attribute differ from setOnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene)

If it's not that, then I'd suspect the context not being available.  You could try using the Activity context like below

`Toast.makeText(this, "Button Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`