# Illegal state exception onclick

Tags: java, android

I am trying to retrieve data by clicking on a button in my activity. I have declared an onclick in activity_second.Here is my code.I am getting am IllegalstateException: method cannot be executed in activity.what is wrong with my code.Why the logcat is showing InvocationTargetException.what exactly this error is and why NullPointerException is there??

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

private EditText loadinfo;
private Button butn1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
loadinfo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
butn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
}

public void apurv1(View view){
File folder = getCacheDir();
File myfile = new File(folder, "mydata1.txt");
String data = readdata(myfile);
if(data!=null){
loadinfo.setText(data);
}
    else {

        loadinfo.setText("no entry was done");
        }
    }



private String readdata(File myfile){

    FileInputStream fis= null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(myfile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int read = -1;
    StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
    try {
        while((read = fis.read())!=-1){
            stringbuffer.append((char)read);
        }
        return stringbuffer.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (fis!=null){
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}   



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

StackTrace is

```
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute      method of the activity
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at    android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     ... 11 more
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at     com.example.storageexternal.SecondActivity.readdata(SecondActivity.java:62)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     at com.example.storageexternal.SecondActivity.apurv1(SecondActivity.java:36)
04-26 00:59:00.545: E/AndroidRuntime(2023):     ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `activity_second` is your xml file and you have an attribute `android:onClick="readdate"` for your button, your readdate method should return void and have an argument of `View`, such as

```
public void readdate (View v) {
    //add code
}
```

or via an OnClickListener

Check this post for more details [How exactly does the android:onClick XML attribute differ from setOnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene)

Comment: <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/status"
        android:onClick="apurv1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/button1" />

Comment: Why the logcat is showing InvocationTargetException. What is this error exactly??