# Android:OnClick Event not functioning

Tags: java, android, android-event

I have imageView  for play and stop and I have tried to implement OnClickListener. But the click event is not handled. Even if I try to start the application in debug mode then also I am not able to detect click event. What could be the error in this code ?

```
public class DetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnClickListener {

    MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.details_activity);
        try {
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.baabaa);
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.stop:
            mp.stop();
            break;
        case R.id.play:
            mp.start();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What are import statements for click?

Comment: import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;

Comment: @AnkitGarg Where is `setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);`? Where is Initialization of `ImageView` and `ClickListener`?

Comment: Too many questions on onClickListeners you are asking.. Why do not read the documentation once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U haven't stated the ImageView in the activity for example

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.XXX);
img.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then  the onClick will work.

If you have asssigned through XML please check the names properly
For XML Check this

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/play"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:layout_gravity="center"
android:contentDescription="playButton" 
android:src="@drawable/play_btn"
android:onClick="myMethod" />
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene) It contains really good inforamtion

Comment: @AnkitGarg Check the edit. These are the fundamental things if it works. Accept the answer.

Comment: @user3726986 I didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

You need to set onClick listener on both your image views. Implementing onclicklistener is not sufficient. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)

In your case you can add below in you activity,

```
findViewById(R.id.stop).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.play).setOnClickListener(this);
```