# Function is not getting called with the button in Android

Tags: java, android, function, button, findviewbyid

I'm trying to make my first Android application, and here is the problem i met:

When i am tapping the Yes Button, the function onYesButtonClick() is not called. The function is supposed to change the visibility of the TextView with the id TextView1, but when i tap, nothing happens. Here is the activity_main.xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
    android:text="@string/q1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="onYesButtonClick"
    android:text="Yes" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:onClick="onNoButtonClick"
    android:text="No" />
```

and here is the MainActivity.java:

```
 public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onYesButtonClick(View view){

     TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     textView.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);

}
public void onNoButtonClick(View view){


}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: you have to use setOnClickListener in java file

Comment: @AmanSingh it is not true

Comment: add some log message in onYesButtonClick and check if its been called or not

Comment: @blackbelt in that case can you give the answer. i will be glad to learn new way of declaring.

Comment: @AmanSingh refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya the function is called, and shows me a Toast, but it doesn't work when i'm trying to change the visibility of the textView1

Comment: @VIOO66 initialize your textview  in onCreate method, [see below answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25447441/991085)

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya oh i missed onclick on xml. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare `textView` in `onCreate` method because `findViewById` available in context of activity methods. So Change  your code as

```
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    }

    public void onYesButtonClick(View view){
       textView.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
  }
```

Comment: I tried to change this way, but the same result, it is not changing the visibility

Comment: @VIOO66 Happy to help,enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void onYesButtonClick(View view){

    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

public void onNoButtonClick(View view){
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//this should be in your onCreate methord
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

public void onYesButtonClick(View view){

     if(view.getID()==R.id.button1){
     textView.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```