# Setting OnClick() for an android view

Tags: android, xml, onclick

Is it a bad programming practice to set `onClick()` method in the `layout XML` file instead of setting `OnClickListener()` in the `java code` in an android activity?

Comment: There are some considerations to take into account, check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**,not at all,

- Whenever you set some listener by `setOnClickListener()` in java
  class,then you are doing it yourself
- but when you specify `onClick` in `xml` file,you are commanding to
  `android` to implement the `setOnClickListener` for you

.However in both cases the `setOnClickListener` is getting implemented.
You may decide according to your requirements which approach you want to follow.