# Android - Onclick event on ActionBar with Custom View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Clicking on the item that is associated with the onclick event, the app closes unexpectedly showing an error. The very strange thing is that this happens only with the item that is in the ActionBar, but the same code works correctly with the items that are in the layout of the activity.

The class:

```
public class myclass extends ActionBarActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_myclass);
            getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_myclass);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        }

        public void myonlickevent(View v) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }

}
```

R.layout.actionbar_myclass (the dots are my code, useless for a reason that I will explain later):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:onClick="myonlickevent" >
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method myonlickevent(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RelativeLayout with id 'myrelativelayoutid'.
```

The problem occurs when I updated `compileSdkVersion` and all dependencies to the latest version, in fact before this my code worked. How to fix?

Comment: Remove `android:onClick` and add an `onClickListener` to the layout.

Comment: @akash93 I'll try it, thanks, but why now I need to do this?

Comment: first of all you declare an onClick in the layout but you dont declare a listener for it...thats why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:onClick` looks for the function in the current activity. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene) for a detailed explanation. And @KostasMatrix that is not true..