# Selector and shape

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button.I am using xml for this button.

Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/shareButtonBgClickedColor" />

    <item android:drawable="@color/shareButtonBgColor" >
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:bottomLeftRadius="13dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="13dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="13dp"
                android:topRightRadius="13dp" />    
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

It reads background color but doesn't read border radius.How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
      android:radius="14dp"
    />
</shape>
```

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene