# Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener' - AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-button

I'm relatively a rookie/beginner with Java/Android programming. I've been trying to make it so while I press a given button in my application it produces a DTMF tone, but when I try to use setOnTouchListener the Android Studio shows me that error. It also gives me an error for MotionEvent which states *Expression expected*

Here are the important parts of the code:

```
boolean pressedCCW = false;
    class SendCCWTone extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0){
            ToneGenerator toneGen;
            toneGen = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF,100);
            while(pressedCCW){
                toneGen.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_DTMF_1);
            }
            toneGen.stopTone();
            toneGen.release();
            createLog("CCW");
            return null;
        }
    }

final Button buttonCCW = (Button) findViewById(R.id.counter_clockwise);
    buttonCCW.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){// Where the error is
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){// Where the other error is located
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if(pressedCCW == false){
                        pressedCCW = true;
                        new SendCCWTone().execute();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    pressedCCW = false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are creating `OnTouchListener` inside of `setOnClickListener`. If you need `TouchListener` then you should register using `setOnTouchListener` instead of `setOnClickListener`

```
buttonCCW.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if(pressedCCW == false){
                        pressedCCW = true;
                        new SendCCWTone().execute();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    pressedCCW = false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved if you place setOnTouchListener inside the onCreate() method of your activity.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this to your code :

```
 implements View.OnTouchListener
```

and use setOnTouchListner instead of setOnClickListener.

```
buttonCCW.setOnListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){// Where the error is
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){// Where the other error is located
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(pressedCCW == false){
                    pressedCCW = true;
                    new SendCCWTone().execute();
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                pressedCCW = false;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Sushrita, where should I exactly put 'implements View.OnTouchListener'?

Thanks! :)

Comment: At your class starting  Like this :  'public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {'

Answer (score -1):

Rather than use `setOnClickListener`, you can set onClick in the XML and point to a method (it does the same thing and looks nicer). In this case, you'd have a method like produceSound:

```
public void produceSound(View view) {
  // your onClick method
}
```

and in the activity's XML, find where that button, `counter_clockwise`, is and add: `android:onClick="produceSound"` to the button's XML.

More here if you're curious: [How exactly does the android:onClick XML attribute differ from setOnClickListener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene)

However, if you're using onTouch, then you will have to stick with what everyone else is suggesting. XML does not support an `android:onTouch` attribute.

Comment: Yeah, in this case I'm working with onTouch since I wish to have the application producing the sound while the button is held down.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your answer if you've solved it--just for other people who may need this for reference. (And no problem as always.)