# Android How to set click listener of a button which is from another layout xml file

Tags: android, android-layout

MainActivity shows a viewpager
so there are 3 layout files:activity_main.xml、card1.xml and card2.xml
Now I want to get view from card1.xml and set the listener.
what should I do?

I tried using this:

```
LayoutInflater layout=this.getLayoutInflater();
View view=layout.inflate(R.layout.card1, null);
Button b=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.b);
```

then set OnClickListener:

```
b.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(0));
```

but useless.

Comment: you have to use adapter for this.

Answer (score 3):

In your card1.xml, you can add a onClick attribute, and just provide the method name as the attribute's value, like this:

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Click me!"
android:onClick="myMethod" />
```

Now in you MainActivity.java file, create a **public** method with **return type as void**, and which takes in a **View parameter**, like this:

```
    public void myMethod(View v) {  
    // do your thing here  
    }
```

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.your_btn_id:
            // your code 

            break;


        }

    }

}
```

another way is you can add button click listener in your card1.xml fragment class.