# Have to click a button twice for it to work in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-view, onclicklistener

So I am currently creating an app and one of the small things that have been bothering me is the fact that I have to click a button twice for it to work.

This is my code and I can't see anything wrong with it:

```
public void signUpButtonClickAction(View v){
    Button signUpButtonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
    signUpButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class));
        }
    });
}
```

xml code for my button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/signUps"
    android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="signUpButtonClickAction"/>
```

It is probably a small fix but even I can't spot this bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

Remove the line `android:onClick="signUpButtonClickAction"` and add

```
Button signUpButtonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
signUpButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class));
    }
});
```

to the `onCreate` method of your activity or the `onCreateView` method of your fragment.

**Alternative Solution**

Alternatively, change the code to this

```
public void signUpButtonClickAction(View v) { 
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class));
}
```

**Explanation**

The line `android:onClick="signUpButtonClickAction"` in the xml is causing an internal call to signUpButtonClick.setOnClickListener(), so you don't have to set up an onClickListener in the `signUpButtonClickAction` again.

**Initializing multiple buttons**

```
private void initializeButtons() {
    Button signUpButtonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
    signUpButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class));
        }
    });

    Button anotherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.anotherButton);
    anotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Clicked on another button!");
        }
    });
}
```

Now simply call `initializeButtons()` from the `onCreate` method of your activity.

Comment: Hi, why did you remove the `onClickListener`? I think it works otherwise but now I am confused as to why there is no listener :/

Comment: What you were doing is to set a new onClickListener upon first click on the button. If you are using `android:onClick="signUpButtonClickAction"` in your xml, Android already sets the onClickListener internally to the method you specified - signUpButtonClickAction in this case.

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz A listener is set by the framework and calls the method you mentioned in `android:onClick`.

Comment: @SamuelGeorgeszusz The line 'android:onClick="signUpButtonClickAction"' makes sure that your listener function is called when the signup button is clicked

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explaination - it makes sense. I never knew that the `android:onClick="signUpButtonClickAction"` makes a function call to listener. Now I know, and as you have explained it well and weren't rude therefore I have upvoted and accepted your answer :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help you out! I updated the post, and now list using  `android:onClick` in the xml as the alternative solution, as I think manually setting the onClickListener is cleaner and less confusing.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have multiple methods like `addUserButtonClickAction()`? Like how would I manually add the `onClickListener` to those?

Comment: Are you talking about initializing multiple buttons? What I usually do is to use a private helper function in `onCreate` that initializes every view element in my activity.

Comment: @mcwise do you mind please showing me an example of this private helper function in `onCreate`? Thanks

Comment: see my edit - did I correctly understand your question?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are setting two times a onClick action. In your xml code you have just asign an onClick() to your button, you don't need to setOnClickListener() inside the `signUpButtonClickAction(View v)`. You have two options:

Leave the xml file like it is and inside `signUpButtonClickAction(View v)` do :

```
public void signUpButtonClickAction(View v){
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class));
}
```

**OR**

Remove the onClick of your xml file:

```
<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/signUps"
android:id="@+id/signUpButton"
android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>
```

And do this in your Activity:

```
Button yourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I will still upvote your answer as I have already accepted the previous answer. Just out of interest, how do I program a button so that it asks the user if they still want to go back?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question, whatever action you would like to be carried out when a button  is pressed you have to write it inside the onClick(). It will depend on what you are trying to do exactly, but just as an example, you can create a LinearLayout with visibility `View.GONE`, and when you click on the button you change the visibility of the LinearLayout to `View.VISIBLE` which contains two buttons, one for going back and another one for moving to the next activity,

Answer (score 0):

The **cause** of the problem is : `onclick()` and `onClickListener` are literally the same! And you are implementing both, the end result is you'll need to press the button twice to start the Activity!

- [See this question for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene)

**FIX:**

The solution to your problem is :

**1:**

```
public void signUpButtonClickAction(View v)
{
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class));
}
```

**2:**

```
Button signUpButtonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);
signUpButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

as mcwise said 
    android:onClick="signUpButtonClickAction"
and 
    signUpButtonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class));
        }
        });
does the same thing. so you have to go with one of them. Having the two is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

For whom it may concern:
I had the same issue but none of the solutions above solved it.
For some reason I cannot understand, I had in my button this line of code:

`android:textIsSelectable="true"`

Deleting this attribute from the button makes it work.

This obviously made the first click to select the text, and the second click triggered the onClick button.