# Android Studio Event Listener mysteries (to me) (setOnClickEventListener)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, event-listener

I am trying to learn android programming and I am stuck at one point, in terms of deeply understanding the concept.

So there is this code which listens the click event for a view (a button). Code is from a site by the way, and working just fine. But I am obsessed with understanding it to the nuts and bolts.

```
clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // do some stuff
    }
});
```

I have questions in some different levels:

**1.** So the parent function (clearButton.setOnClickListener) is the event handler, as far as I can tell, which is trigerred when the button is clicked. And yet we are passing it an object's method, which, as far as I can tell, another event listener. Both of them are named as "ClickListener" so I am confused. Are two of them really event listeners?

**2.** Where did the View object (one which passed as the callback) came from? Is it implicitly created by the system? I have no such definition in my MainActivity.java file.

**3.** I clumsly tried to write it with parent function invoking another simple function which just displays an AlertDialog, but I was badly failed, since clearButton.setOnClickEventListener expects a View to be returned from callback (I think:)). Is there any other way to accomplish it or this is the only way setting an event listener to a view? Do I have to accept it the way it is and embrace it, instead of struggling with it :) I ask this only to understand the logic of the structure, code works just fine.

**4.** What is the view passed to the View.OnClickListener function? Is it the current view (I doubt it is)?  What is the use case of the view passed to the View.

**5.** Where can I (or can I) review the code of the View.OnClickListener function to better understand it?

**6.** All this exercise trigerred another question in my mind about callbacks, but it is probably subject of another question altogether :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's a little bit hard to explain, but you are passing what you can treat as a `function`.
2. [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) is included in the Android Framework.
3. You can also set the `onClick` listener via the xml. Check this very helpful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene).
4. From how I understand it, it's the view it is tied to. For example, it is an onClickListener for a `button1`, the view is referring to `button1`.
5. [View.OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html)
6. ...Okay. I think it would be good for you to go through tutorials first (I suggest [udacity](https://www.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837) :D )

Not very definitive, but I hope this gives you an idea somehow. Happy Learning and Coding! Cheers! :D

Comment: Thanks a lot, reading the android reference page made it much more clear. 

I've been going through a lot of tutorials lately, and I felt that it was going wayyy to slow, so I decided to get my hands dirty. They got dirtier then I expected :) 

Udacity tutorial you suggested seems nice though, I will look into it. Thanks again and cheers :)