# Unexpected Intent behavior - error onClick

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have two buttons, yes and no. When I click the yes button, it works fine and loads the next activity. However, when I press no it errors. I have switched the XML `onclick` on the no button to the yes method and it works fine so it can't me the XML, can it?

Inside my FlowIntent.java:

```
class FlowIntent {
    public Intent Yes;
    public Intent No;
}
```

Inside my MainActivity.java:

```
package capri.capritestapplication;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FlowIntent Flow = new FlowIntent();
    @Override    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // should be dynamic
        this.Flow.No = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        this.Flow.Yes = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
    }
    public void loadQuestionNo(View view) {
        startActivity(this.Flow.No);
    }
    public void loadYes(View view) {
        startActivity(this.Flow.Yes);
    }
}
```

Inside my MainActivity2.java AND MainActivity3 (which works for 2):

```
package capri.capritestapplication;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FlowIntent Flow = new FlowIntent();
    @Override    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
    }
    public void loadQuestionNo(View view) {
        // todo
    }
    public void loadYes(View view) {
        // todo
    }
}
```

Inside my XML:

```
<Button
        android:text="No"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:onClick="loadYes" />

<Button
        android:text="No"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="loadQuestionNo" />
```

My error log is:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: capri.capritestapplication, PID: 2384
>                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method loadQuestionNo(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Comment: post complete log and complete code to get better understanding

Comment: Bare with me then @androidXP Will do now

Comment: We need more details.Especially the code inside  **OnClickListener** and **MainActivity3.onCreate()**.

Comment: Updated the coce @androidXP

Comment: Problem is not in Intent but as we can see from logs : loadQuestionNo(View), it could not determine this method.

Comment: Why couldn't it? It seems to determine the loadYes(View) :/ @Rafal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <Button
        android:text="No"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="loadYes" />

<Button
        android:text="No"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:elevation="3dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="loadQuestionNo" />
```

Look at your XML code.Both button has same id `android:id="@+id/button"`. Your Button id must be unique for every view

As your updated question i suggest you to change the name of the method which you call from XML. change your method name in xml as well as in your activities.

It would be better if you show complete code with xml that would help us to suggest you edits.

Comment: my bad they are different ID's, I couldn't copy and paste the code directly from the sofware as I'm on a different PC - ill update code

Comment: it keeps saying that MainActivity3 cannot be found now

Answer (score 0):

Instead using `android:onClick` in XML layout get yours view by `findViewById()` and set `onClickListner` of each button and execute this from your code instead of XML itself.

Comment: updated the code plus I don't know how to use onClickListner yet

Comment: There is simple example how to use it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene