# Very Simple onClick Android App not working

Tags: java, android, button, onclick

My Android App Will Crashing when i clicked the button.
I am running this on my device using android device. i not sure if my code are at fault or something else
Device: Xiomi Note 4G
android ver. 4.4 Android KitKat API 19
Android studio 2.2.3

[Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0bDx.png)  [Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57NGA.png)

1.activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.pckreatif.buttonclicked2.MainActivity">
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="onClickButton (MainActivity)" />
<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

2.MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void onClickButton(View v){
    TextView text1;
    text1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    text1.setText("TEST");
}
}
```

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify method reference as following:

```
android:onClick="onClickButton"
```

So your `Button` should be:

```
<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="onClickButton" />
```

Comment: this code here there are auto add by Android Studio IDE when i pick onclick under button property. Never suspect that part to causing my app to crash.

Comment: @pckreatif looks strange. Android Studio never suggested such `onClick` property to me

Answer (score 2):

try with just... why do you need params there, no need to write that way.

```
onClick="onClickButton"
```

Comment: we did it at the same time. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
android:onClick="onClickButton (MainActivity)"
```

to

```
android:onClick="onClickButton"
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace your `onClick` method name from `onClickButton (MainActivity)` to `onClickButton` Because space is not allowed in `onClick`

Just Replace your **activity_main.xml** with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.pckreatif.buttonclicked2.MainActivity">
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="onClickButton"/>
    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```