# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method btnSubmit(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick

Tags: java, android, xml

This Java takes the inputs of Edit Text fields and outputs them into Toast.

I have no idea where or what the error is, any help would be greatly appreciated:

**Java**

```
package colonyapplication.colony;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class tenantReg extends Activity {

    EditText fullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFname);
    EditText userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    EditText userPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPass);

    String fName = fullName.getText().toString();
    String uEmail = userEmail.getText().toString();
    String uPass = userPass.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tenant_reg);
    }

    public void btnSubmit() {

        String tenant = "Tenant";

        Toast.makeText(tenantReg.this, "UserName is: " + fName + ". Password is: " + uPass + "email is: " + uEmail + tenant, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#fcdfaa"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="colonyapplication.colony.tenantReg">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:src="@drawable/colonylogo"
    android:layout_above="@+id/passTextBox"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etFname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Full Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etEmail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etFname"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etFname"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPass"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etEmail"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etEmail"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etEmail" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etPassconfirm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Confirm Password"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPass"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etPass"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etPass" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:background="#EE7600"
    android:onClick="btnSubmit"
    android:text="Submit"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etPassconfirm"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etPassconfirm" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:background="#EE7600"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etPassconfirm"
    android:layout_marginEnd="33dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

For whatever reason, when the submit button is clicked, the program stops in the emulator. The error in the Android Monitor states: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method btnSubmit(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button'"

Answer (score 0):

As I see you have 2 Button but I dont know which one is submit button.
well also I can not find the meaning of `public void btnSubmit()`. As I know you should define tn submit:

```
Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_btnSubmit_id);
```

and then use onClickListener method to do somthing when btn clicked

```
btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //Do somthing
        }
    });
```

#### Edit:

You can use your code just replace

```
public void btnSubmit()
```

with this:

```
public void btnSubmit(View v)
```

Comment: btnSubmit is defined  within the XML as the onClick. "android:onClick="btnSubmit"" So simply public void btnSubmit(){} works fine. I've done it that way for a few years

Comment: I do have to aplogise for the scruffy XML code, but as Android Studio is drag and drop as well as hard code, it's easy to become lazy

Comment: OK, i am sorry. i didnt see that but as i know you should use (View v) on submit click. like this link [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4153842/7699710](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4153842/7699710)

Comment: Hi, cheers for the reply, (view v) isn't working either, I think it must be something really boring within the code!

Comment: In fact, I tried to set the other button (cancel) to do this:                       public void btnCancel(View v){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_page);
    }  and even that threw the same error

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: `@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tenant_reg);

public void btnSubmit() {

        String tenant = "Tenant";

        Toast.makeText(tenantReg.this, "UserName is: " + fName + ". Password is: " + uPass + "email is: " + uEmail + tenant, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    }

}`