# Android Studio error: @Override not applicable to field

Tags: java, android, overriding

I am fairly new to android development and as my first app I want to make a flashlight app. So the first steps I want to do is to make a button in the center such that it changes it's text to "ON" and "OFF" alternately after every click. I made the java code but it Android studio gives me this error: '@Override' not applicable to field. Here is my java code:

```
    package com.danielfernandzz.flashlight;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean switchState = false;
    Button switchbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Switch);
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void Switched(View v){

        if(!switchState){
            switchState = true;
            switchbutton.setText("OFF");
        }else{
            switchState = false;
            switchbutton.setText("ON");
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my xml code (in case you need it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.danielfernandzz.flashlight.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Switch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="Switched"
        android:text="ON"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried commenting out the @Override and no error came. But when I ran the app, it crashed so I assume that the app crashed because @Override wasn't there?
I don't understand why this is happening to me, I have seen other questions but their error is something different.
NOTE: I am using the latest version Android Studio 3.0

Comment: why would you want that annotation there? what purpose would it serve?

Comment: check this it may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene

Comment: move your `@Override` before `onCreate()` not before your variable `switchState`

Comment: you also may want to re-think your logic. your Switched method, for instance. why don't you follow naming convention and call it switched instead of Switched? why do you pass a parameter you don't use? the code within can be reduced to: switchButton.setText(switchState ? "ON" : "OFF"); switchState = !switchState;

Comment: I tried that, the error was gone but my app still crashes. I think it's crashing for some other reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

1.move you `switchbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Switch);` inside your `onCreate()` method

2.place `@Override`  before `onCreate()`

**sample code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public boolean switchState = false;
    Button switchbutton ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        switchbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Switch);
    }

    public void Switched(View v){

        if(!switchState){
            switchState = true;
            switchbutton.setText("OFF");
        }else{
            switchState = false;
            switchbutton.setText("ON");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did that but I got another error saying "Variable switchbutton not used" and the switchbutton in if else statement was highlighted red (cannot resolve symbol)

Comment: **1. error saying "Variable switchbutton not used"** because your **switchbutton** is never used @ThatDanielFernandes

Comment: Hey, you were right, I didn't notice the "Button switchbutton ;" . Now I added that it worked, but still crashes when I click a button. I think because of some other prblem, but atleast override is solved

Comment: share your crash log with question @ThatDanielFernandes

Comment: After some tweaking, I got it working! Thanks to everyone here who helped me. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

As according @Jerrol you can place the @Override before onCreate. There is no need to place it before variable initialization.Could you give us the crash log that you are getting after removal.