# Call a method with parameters in java

Tags: java, android

I want to call this method in onClick

```
public void estimateFare(final String distance, final String time){

      //more code

}
```

Comment: what about creating an object??

Comment: Okay... what is your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene

Comment: i have a button to send the data but I don't know how to call this method

Answer (score 0):

```
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
        implements View.OnClickListener { 
        private Button mButton; 
        private final String distance;
        private final String time;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

            mButton = findViewById(R.id.button_send); 
            mButton.setOnClickListener(this); 
        } 

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) 
        { 
          estimateFare(this.distance, this.time)
        } 
      }
```

You need to set your listener and then override the onClick method.
onClick will be called when the mButton will be pressed.