# Does Guice use reflection, and if so does it affect performance?

Tags: reflection, guice

If I have a high-throughput system, should I avoid using Guice to inject objects that are created frequently? Some one has asked how reflection affects performance and it seems pretty bad: [Java Reflection Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435553/java-reflection-performance).

Answer (score 6):

Guice uses reflection quite heavily.

Reflection on the desktop/server JVM is very efficient, and even very large Guice applications don't have performance problems related to Guice.

Reflection on Android is much less efficient, particularly on older Gingerbread and Froyo devices. [Dagger](http://square.github.com/dagger/) is an open source Guice alternative designed to run efficiently on Android.

Comment: Note that google discourage using guice on Google App Engine.