# How to use a String value in order to call class attribute

Tags: java

Let's say I have Java class:

```
public class Animal
{
    public String dog = "Rex";
}
```

In another class I am doing like this:

```
 Animal mAnimal = new Animal();
 String attributeCaller = "dog";
```

**PROBLEM:** how to call mAnimal attribute "dog" by using String "attributeCaller" value in Java? I mean to do something like this:

```
 String dogName = mAnimal.attributeCaller;
```

which simply should be equal to (convenient way of calling attributes in Java):

```
 String dogName = mAnimal.dog;
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are asking?

Comment: I dont get it either

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using Java Reflection API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/. However, I would not recommend using Reflection unless it is really necessary.

Comment: +1 for recommandation, but I advice against also,  reflexion usage is not supposed to fix lousy design...

Comment: ps: reflexion is slow! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435553/java-reflection-performance

Answer (score 1):

You can use java reflection API to inspect the content of any object and achieve that.
Here is an example:

```
String attributeCaller = "dog";
Animal mAnimal = new Animal();
Class<?> c = mAnimal.getClass();

Field f = c.getDeclaredField(attributeCaller);
f.setAccessible(true);

String dogName = (String) f.get(mAnimal);
```

Please notice that this doesn't work for superclass fields, to get superclass fields you have to iterate through `c.getSuperclass()` to find the field

Answer (score 0):

Those seem to be two different classes so that idea will not work.
You have one class called `Animal` which has a String attribute called `dog`. Now in another class where you have created an Object of type `Animal`,in this case that object is called `mAnimal`,you have to refer to its attribute by the object name,so the variable `dogName` can be assigned the value of the object like:
`String dogName=mAnimal.dog;` 
 or perhaps you want to set that object's attribute like:
`mAnimal.dog = "Snoopy";` .
It seems you may understand how Classes and Objects work, I would recommend watching the Lynda.com videos on Java for Beginners or getting the Java How To Program by the Deitel brothers.
If that was helpful consider giving it a point up