# Can Java dereference a statement?

Tags: java

Can Java do something like this ?:

```
String methodName = "multiply";

MyMath myMath = new MyMath();

/* "methodName" is expanded before being called */
int answer = myMath.methodName(2, 3);    

System.out.println(answer);

6
```

Is this type of feature / concept in a programming language known as "dynamic expansion", "variable interpolation", eval() (e.g. in various scripting languages), reflection, introspection, Java beans?

Comment: as far as I know, you can't. Why do you need it?

Comment: @c-an - Well, I am trying to put a method name in a properties file eg. "methodName = multiply" and then call it in the program without having to hardcode it or use `switch` or `if ... else if` or factory design patterns.

Comment: I guess in this case, you need to use params and implement that you want to achieve.

Comment: It feels like a [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Answer (score 5):

Java doesn't provide this behaviour as a standard language feature, however it can be achieved with [the Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/):

```
MyMath myMath = new MyMath();
String methodName = "multiply";
Method m = MyMath.class.getMethod(methodName);
m.invoke(myMath, 2, 3);
```

Comment: It is same as calling the function and telling what to do based on condition.

Comment: That being said, please note that the need for using reflection often indicates a bad design/architecture. So if possible, think about refactoring your code first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible Reflection, however the performance is poor (confirmed in [Java Reflection Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435553/java-reflection-performance)).

Instructions about Reflection: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javareflection.html

This article describes how to use reflection. For you, the section "Invoking Methods by Name" would be the most interesting, but I recommend to read the whole article.

Comment: *"however the performce is poor"* Citation?

Comment: That comes from my personal experience. A quick search leaded me to this confirmation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435553/java-reflection-performance. Of course Oracle does not tell you the bad aspects of their Product.

Comment: I would not say that anyone, including Oracle, tries to intentionally hide this fact. It is not that fast due to how it is implemented. It is more a technical limitation right now. And there are efforts to change that with newer versions.