# Java reflection run-time performance

Tags: java, performance, reflection

This is an academical exercise (disclaimer).

I'm building an application that will profit from being **as fast as possible** as it will compete with others.

I know that declaring a class using reflection (example below) will suffer a huge penalty as opposed to a standard declaration.

```
Class mDefinition = Class.forName("MySpecialClassString");
Constructor mConstructor = mDefinition.getConstructor(new Class[]{MySpecialClass.class});
myClass = (MySpecialClass) mConstructor.newInstance(this);
```

However, after declaring `myClass` if I use it in a standard fashion `myClass.myMethod()` **will I also suffer from performance hogs** or will it be the same as if I had declared the class in a standard fashion?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There will be a performance penalty when you first instantiate the object. Once the class is loaded, its the same as if it had been instantiated normally, and there will be no further performance penalty.

Going further, if you call methods using reflection, there will be a performance penalty for about fifteen times (default in Java), after which the reflected call will be rewritten by the JVM to be the exact same as a statically compiled call. Therefore, even repeatedly reflected method calls will not cause a performance decrease, once that bytecode has been recompiled by the JVM.

See these two link for more information on that:

- [Any way to further optimize Java reflective method invocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414801/any-way-to-further-optimize-java-reflective-method-invocation)
- http://inferretuation.blogspot.com/2008/11/in-jit-we-trust.html

Comment: thks for the pretty detailed description and the extra documentation. Really proved useful on these last couple of days.

Answer (score 7):

Once the class has been loaded you should be fine.  The overhead is associated with inspecting the runtime structures that represent the class, etc.  Calling methods in a standard fashion should be fine, however if you start searching for methods by name or signature, that will incur additional overhead.

Comment: +1 agreed - there should be no great expense for a one-shot dynamic lookup.

Comment: @Chris I've been running some tests and you are right on point with your assumptions. Thanks for pre-clearing this up.

Answer (score 2):

Chris Thompson's answer is on the mark. However I'm confused by your code example.

this will dynamically load the class:

```
Class mDefinition = Class.forName("MySpecialClassString");
```

This will get a `Contructor` for your class, which takes an instance of that same class as an argument. Also note that you're accessing the class at compile time with `MySpecialClass.class`:

```
Constructor mConstructor = mDefinition.getConstructor(new Class[]{MySpecialClass.class});
```

This is instantiating a `MySpecialClass` by passing `this` into the constructor:

```
myClass = (MySpecialClass) mConstructor.newInstance(this);
```

Based on the constructor argument, does that mean we are in an instance method of `MySpecialClass`? Very confused.

**EDIT:** This is closer to what I would have expected to see:

```
Class<?> mDefinition = Class.forName("MySpecialClassString");

//constructor apparently takes this as argument
Class<?> constructorArgType = this.getClass(); //could be ThisClassName.class

Constructor<?> mConstructor = mDefinition.getConstructor(constructorArgType);

MySpecialInterface mySpecialInstance = (MySpecialInterface)mConstructor.newInstance(this);
```

where `MySpecialInterface` is an interface used to interact with your dynamically loaded classes:

```
interface MySpecialInterface {
    //methods used to interface with dynamically loaded classes
}
```

Anyway please let me know if I'm misunderstanding or off base here.

Comment: you're probably right as I'm just starting to use reflection now. Let me brief you very fast on how the system works. We've got three classes ClassA_interaction, ClassB_object and ClassC_logic... ClassA_interaction launches several ClassB_objects and feeds them with positions. Every ClassB_object launch a ClassC_logic using reflection. ClassC_logic is feed with `this` (ClassB_object) as they have to call functions that exist on ClassB_object.

It can be messy but works. Would you suggest I take another approach? Thks for taking the time to look at my code.

Comment: I have to say I haven't personally worked with dynamic classloading, which is why I wanted confirmation from someone. But, my understanding is that if you directly reference a class in your code or even have access to it at compile time, there is no point to dynamically loading it.  However, it would make sense if you have a statically loaded `Foo` which is either an abstract class or interface, and your dynamically loaded classes extend/implement `Foo`. That way after you dynamically load a class and instantiate it, you can cast it to `Foo` and interact with it without further reflection.

Comment: Of course, `Foo` needs to know everything you're going to want to do with these dynamically loaded classes, in the form of abstract/interface method declarations.

Comment: The dynamic class-loading (on my case) serves only one purpose, the game is  feed with a txt file that has the name of a map. The maps are pre-given and we can (should) have different strategies for each map. Therefore the name of the map will determine which class to load.

Comment: Can these different strategies fall under common abstract methods? Also, what is the reason for dynamically loading the classes - speed? A class that's available at compile time will still not be loaded until it's needed at runtime. Or will these maps/behaviors not be available until *during* runtime?

Comment: Actually you're somewhat right in assuming that the strategies fall under common abstract methods. They all extend a `CommonStrat()` class. Having the strategy load at runtime is not a personal option, just something I have to comply with (it is correct to assume that the map will only be provided at runtime). Given this scenario what made the most sense to me was to use reflection but I may be utterly wrong in my assumptions.

Comment: It's sounds like you're on track - so dynamically loaded strategies will be cast to `CommonStrat` and then you can interact with them normally using methods declared by the `CommonStrat` class. This will allow new maps/strategies to be plugged in at runtime. Makes sense to me, though you could always mull this over in the form of a question if you wanted to get confirmation from people with more dynamic classloading knowledge than me. Good luck.