# Why are the call stacks different when a test crashes at the exact same statement?

Tags: java, reflection, junit

For a research project, I'm trying to figure out if unit tests (written in JUnit) behave differently when executed in different contexts. For this I do two things: first, I run the entire test suite of a program with my custom JUnit Runner, and then I run a single test using the same custom JUnit runner (It's not important why this makes sense, just accept it for now). When tests fail, I record the entire exception stack trace as it is reported by JUnit, and then compare the stack traces between the two runs.

Doing this, I stumbled about something odd that I can't explain. Below are two excerpts from two stack traces recorded that way.

Stack trace recorded when running the entire test suite:

```
org.fest.swing.edt.GuiActionRunner.resultOf(GuiActionRunner.java:126)
org.fest.swing.edt.GuiActionRunner.execute(GuiActionRunner.java:73)
net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.datasetviewer.cellcomponent.AbstractNumericDataTypeUITest.constructTestFrameInEDT(AbstractNumericDataTypeUITest.java:98)
net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.datasetviewer.cellcomponent.AbstractNumericDataTypeUITest.setUp(AbstractNumericDataTypeUITest.java:81)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source) - sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
```

Stack trace recorded when running a single test:

```
org.fest.swing.edt.GuiActionRunner.resultOf(GuiActionRunner.java:126)
org.fest.swing.edt.GuiActionRunner.execute(GuiActionRunner.java:73)
net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.datasetviewer.cellcomponent.AbstractNumericDataTypeUITest.constructTestFrameInEDT(AbstractNumericDataTypeUITest.java:98)
net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.datasetviewer.cellcomponent.AbstractNumericDataTypeUITest.setUp(AbstractNumericDataTypeUITest.java:81)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
```

Both stack traces show the last few entries before the crash, starting from the last common statement. Clearly, somewhere inside the reflection implementation in the JDK/VM something behaves differently between these two cases.

**My question is why?**

I speculate that this has something to do with the VM caching stuff from earlier reflective calls or something, but I don't really know. This is important to know, because I have to figure out if this is going to happen *every time* I run a single test (and thus I can ignore it), or if this has something to do with the specific test I'm running.

I know this is rather vague, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: *"I  speculate that this has something to do with the VM caching stuff from earlier reflective calls"* : very unlikely - probably due to the specific implementation of the methods called in the testing framework. Corollary: this should be a consistent behaviour from one run to another.

Comment: It is certainly consistent between runs. If I had an easy means to check if the same thing happens in cases where no exception is thrown I'd be happy. But going in with instrumentation to figure this out may be a bit overkill.

Comment: Have you checked the source code corresponding to each item in the stack trace to try to follow the execution path?

Comment: No, because the differences are in the JDK, and I don't have the sources for the JDK this ran on.

Comment: Google: `sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl .java` => http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/reflect/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java

Comment: Now I feel stupid. Thanks :))

Comment: Until you know it, you don't! Have fun with your investigation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the Sun/Oracle JVM(others I dunno) optimizes reflection invocations. The JVM since 1.4 generates bytecode to bridge a reflection call to the invoked method.  Because not all things are known at compile time, so it has to be done at runtime.

The class [MethodAccessorGenerator](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/raw-file/2d585507a41b/src/share/classes/sun/reflect/MethodAccessorGenerator.java) generates the `GeneratedMethodAccessor1`

A hint I found from the comments of NativeMethodAccessorImpl:

`Used only for the first few invocations of a Method; afterward, switches to bytecode-based implementation`

Are you running the suite and the single test in the lifecycle of one Java VM?

Comment: @otakun85 No, I'm running them in different VMs, so that would explain why in one case I get the call to the NativeAccessor and in the other I don't.

Comment: @Jochen I would still like to know when exactly it decides to create a bytecode bridge? But that maybe too much investigation at least for me for now ^^

Comment: I has a hard coded constant for that. It simply counts how often a method gets invoked reflectively and if you reach the threshold (in the version I'm using that threshold appears to be 15) it generates the byte-code wrapper.

Comment: @Jochen You might find [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/414801/any-way-to-further-optimize-java-reflective-method-invocation) interesting.

Comment: @assylias Thanks, some of the answers were enlightening.